# Python string prints as [u'String']

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

This will surely be an easy one but it is really bugging me.

I have a script that reads in a webpage and uses [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse it. From the *soup* I extract all the links as my final goal is to print out the link.contents.

All of the text that I am parsing is ASCII. I know that Python treats strings as unicode, and I am sure this is very handy, just of no use in my wee script.

Every time I go to print out a variable that holds 'String' I get `[u'String']` printed to the screen. Is there a simple way of getting this back into just ascii or should I write a regex to strip it?

Comment: possible duplicate of the much more clearly worded question (and answer): https://stackoverflow.com/q/2464959/1390788

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the u prefix in a Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`[u'ABC']` would be a one-element list of unicode strings. [Beautiful Soup always produces Unicode](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit). So you need to convert the list to a single unicode string, and then convert that to ASCII.

I don't know exaxtly how you got the one-element lists; the contents member would be a list of strings and tags, which is apparently not what you have. Assuming that you really always get a list with a single element, and that your test is really *only* ASCII you would use this:

```
 soup[0].encode("ascii")
```

However, please double-check that your data is really ASCII. This is pretty rare. Much more likely it's latin-1 or utf-8.

```
 soup[0].encode("latin-1")


 soup[0].encode("utf-8")
```

Or you ask Beautiful Soup what the original encoding was and get it back in this encoding:

```
 soup[0].encode(soup.originalEncoding)
```

Comment: You actually don't have to do the encoding, because the OP is only seeing the string repr because thats how you see anything when you print a list. soup[0] will be enough to show the str instead of the repr, showing the contents of the string and not the quote and unicode modifier.

Comment: You shouldn't encode the text represented as Unicode to bytes in most  cases: you should print Unicode directly in Python: [`print(', '.join([u'ABC' , u'...']))`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36891685/4279)

Answer (score 27):

You probably have a list containing one unicode string. The `repr` of this is `[u'String']`.

You can convert this to a list of byte strings using any variation of the following:

```
# Functional style.
print map(lambda x: x.encode('ascii'), my_list)

# List comprehension.
print [x.encode('ascii') for x in my_list]

# Interesting if my_list may be a tuple or a string.
print type(my_list)(x.encode('ascii') for x in my_list)

# What do I care about the brackets anyway?
print ', '.join(repr(x.encode('ascii')) for x in my_list)

# That's actually not a good way of doing it.
print ' '.join(repr(x).lstrip('u')[1:-1] for x in my_list)
```

Comment: Please, avoid such horrors as `repr(x).lstrip('u')[1:-1]`. Use something like: `print ", ".join(my_list)` instead, to format a list of Unicode strings.

Comment: The comment, it says: "That's actually not a good way of doing it". It's just here for the lolz!

Answer (score 13):

```
import json, ast
r = {u'name': u'A', u'primary_key': 1}
ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(r))
```

will print

```
{'name': 'A', 'primary_key': 1}
```

Comment: this method looks pretty sweet to me, why no votes? any performance impact we should worry about?

Comment: Just using `import json` and then `print json.dumps(myVar)` did the trick for me, thanks!

Comment: ast is not even needed in my case. json.dumps solved my case. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If accessing/printing single element lists (e.g., sequentially or filtered):

```
my_list = [u'String'] # sample element
my_list = [str(my_list[0])]
```

Comment: you do a list comprehension: `my_list = [str(my_list[x]) for x in range(len(my_list))]`

Answer (score 5):

pass the output to str() function and it will remove the unicode output u''.
also by printing the output it will remove the u'' tags from it.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really mean `u'String'`?

In any event, can't you just do `str(string)` to get a string rather than a unicode-string? (This should be different for Python 3, for which all strings are unicode.)

Comment: I should have been clearer. I am using str() but still getting output like below when I print. 

[u'ABC'] 
[u'DEF'] 
[u'GHI'] 
[u'JKL'] 

The data is stripped as text from a webpage, then inserted into a database (Google Appstore), then retrieved and printed.

Answer (score 4):

`[u'String']` is a text representation of a list that contains a Unicode string on Python 2.

If you run `print(some_list)` then it is equivalent to
`print'[%s]' % ', '.join(map(repr, some_list))` i.e., to create a text representation of a Python object with the type `list`, `repr()` function is called for each item.

**Don't confuse a Python object and its text representation**—`repr('a') != 'a'` and even the text representation of the text representation differs: `repr(repr('a')) != repr('a')`.

`repr(obj)` returns a string that contains a printable representation of an object. Its purpose is to be an unambiguous representation of an object that can be useful for debugging, in a REPL. Often `eval(repr(obj)) == obj`.

To avoid calling `repr()`, you could print list items directly (if they are all Unicode strings) e.g.: `print ",".join(some_list)`—it prints a comma separated list of the strings: `String`

Do not encode a Unicode string to bytes using a hardcoded character encoding, **print Unicode directly** instead. Otherwise, the code may fail because the encoding can't represent all the characters e.g., if you try to use `'ascii'` encoding with non-ascii characters. Or the code silently produces mojibake (corrupted data is passed further in a pipeline) if the environment uses an encoding that is incompatible with the hardcoded encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Use `dir` or `type` on the 'string' to find out what it is. I suspect that it's one of BeautifulSoup's tag objects, that prints like a string, but really isn't one. Otherwise, its inside a list and you need to convert each string separately.

In any case, why are you objecting to using Unicode? Any specific reason?

Comment: I've been looking at BeautifulSoup since the last few days. I couldn't figure out how gnuchu would get u['string'] not [u'String']. His comment to Andrew Jaffe seems to prove it is a list.

Answer (score -3):

`encode("latin-1")` helped me in my case:

```
facultyname[0].encode("latin-1")
```