# Django choices. How to set default option?

Tags: django

How to set default `STATUSES` option ?

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUSES = (
        (u'E', u'Expected'),
        (u'S', u'Sent'),
        (u'F', u'Finished'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, choices=STATUSES)
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, choices=STATUSES, default='E')
```

or to avoid setting an invalid default if STATUSES changes:

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, choices=STATUSES, default=STATUSES[0][0])
```

Answer (score 17):

It's an old question, just wanted to add the now availabel Djanto 3.x+ syntax:

```py
class StatusChoice(models.TextChoices):
    EXPECTED = u'E', 'Expected'
    SENT = u'S', 'Sent'
    FINISHED = u'F', 'Finished'
```

Then, you can use this syntax to set the default:

```py
status = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    null=True,
    choices=StatusChoice.choices,
    default=StatusChoice.EXPECTED
)
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the resource?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types

Comment: this answer helped, but the u'E', confused me for those wondering its just a string with unicode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string

Comment: The unicode designation is also not necessary--it isn't even used in the django docs. Seems to just be a holdover from when the question was asked a long time ago.