# Converting a JSON string (sent via ajax) into a Python list

Tags: python, ajax, json, google-app-engine

I have an array that was converted to a string using JSON.stringify so that I could send the data by ajax to a Python handler.  This allowed me to save the data as a sting...brackets, quotes, and all.  I need this data in some kind of usable list or array...not just a string.  I appreciate any incite you can give, thanks.

**The format of the string that is being saved in the database (datastore - using GAE):**

["SU15AM","SU3AM","SU4AM","SU45AM","SU4PM","M3AM"]

**The javascript/ajax code:**

```
var ids = new Array();

$('.ui-selected').each(function(){ 
    ids.push($(this).attr('value'));    //adds items selected to the array so that they can be passed via ajax
    console.log('**item added to data object**');
});

string_ids = JSON.stringify(ids, null);   //converts array object to a string to pass via ajax

$.ajax({                
    type: "POST",
    url: '/schedule',
    data: {'ids': string_ids},      //string of selected items 
});
```

**Python Handler:**

```
class ScheduleHandler(BaseHandler2):
    time_ids = self.request.get('ids')
    times = AvailableTimes(ids = time_ids)         
    times.put();
```

**Python model:**

```
class AvailableTimes(db.Model): 
    user = db.StringProperty()    
    timezone = db.StringProperty()
    ids = db.StringProperty()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load it via [json.loads()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '["SU15AM","SU3AM","SU4AM","SU45AM","SU4PM","M3AM"]'
>>> l = json.loads(s)
>>> l
[u'SU15AM', u'SU3AM', u'SU4AM', u'SU45AM', u'SU4PM', u'M3AM']
>>> type(l)
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Wow that was a fast response, alecxe!  I am pretty new to Python, can help me understand what the "u" means?  and will that affect how i can use the string? -Thanks

Comment: `u` is just a prefix that means that the string is `unicode`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string.