# Streaming twitter api gives: {u’limit’:{u’track’:240}}

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to retrieve tweets from the streaming api.  I checked and one of the tweets I received was:

```
{u’limit’:{u’track’:240}}
```

I cannot find out what this means.  Does anyone have any info?  FYI, I'm doing this coding in python.  I used json.loads to format the tweet into a python dictionary

Comment: Unicode strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2655