# Segregating text from bold tags within td tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve what is in-between the td tags without any tags in the following:

```
<td class="formSummaryPosition"><b>1</b>/9</td>
```

This is what I have written so far

```
o = []
for race in table:
    for pos in race.findAll("td", {"class":"Position"}):
        o.append(pos.contents)
```

I understand that the .contents will provide me with the follwing:

```
[[<b>1</b>, u'/9'], [<b>4</b>, u'/11'], [<b>2</b>, u'/8'], ...]
```

Ultimately I would like to have:

```
o = [[1/9],[4/11],[2/8]...]
```

I would appreciate if anyone had any idea on how to achieve this most efficiently?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method on an element:

> If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you can use the
>   get_text() method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a
>   tag, as a single Unicode string

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
... <table>
...     <tr>
...         <td class="formSummaryPosition"><b>1</b>/9</td>
...         <td class="formSummaryPosition"><b>4</b>/11</td>
...         <td class="formSummaryPosition"><b>2</b>/8</td>
...     </tr>
... </table>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> print [td.get_text() for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='formSummaryPosition')]
[u'1/9', u'4/11', u'2/8']
```

Comment: That worked well! How would I remove the 'u' before the values now? Thanks very much btw :)

Comment: @user3374113 well, you can call `str()` on each item, but you don't really need. It just means it is a unicode string, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string

Comment: Thanks I figured it out: print [str(td.get_text()) for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='formSummaryPosition')]