# newbie in scrapy : how to response.css scrape the text part?

Tags: python, css-selectors, web-scraping, scrapy

When I practice, I want to catch only the text part (1,2,3,4,5...), without the  part how can I write the response.css("td[class='c1']")?

```
scrapy shell "https://tw.movies.yahoo.com/chart.html"
response.css("td[class='c1']")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two options, one using [`css()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.css), another one using [`xpath()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.xpath):

```
>>> response.css("td.c1 > span::text").extract()
[u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'10', u'11', u'12', u'13', u'14', u'15', u'16', u'17', u'18', u'19', u'20']
>>> response.xpath("//td[@class='c1']/span/text()").extract()
[u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'10', u'11', u'12', u'13', u'14', u'15', u'16', u'17', u'18', u'19', u'20']
```

Comment: Wow it's amazing!!But is there a way to remove the 'u'?

Comment: @user2492364 it is just a [unicode literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string), don't worry about it.

Comment: you can remove the u by doing after all that .encode('utf8')

Comment: In your code - `response.css("td[class='c1']")`, you can add `::text` before the quotes: response.css("td[class='c1']::text")