# Create vocabulary dictionary for text mining

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

I have the following code:

```
train_set = ("The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright.")
test_set = ("The sun in the sky is bright.",
    "We can see the shining sun, the bright sun.")
```

Now Im trying to calculate the word frequency like this:

```
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
```

Next I would like to print the voculabary. Therefore I do:

```
vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set)
print vectorizer.vocabulary
```

Right now I get the ouput none. While I expect something like:

```
{'blue': 0, 'sun': 1, 'bright': 2, 'sky': 3}
```

Any thoughts where this goes wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CountVectorizer does not print vocabulary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894756/countvectorizer-does-not-print-vocabulary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
print vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

Answer (score 4):

`CountVectorizer` doesn't support what you are looking for.

You can use the `Counter` class:

```
from collections import Counter

train_set = ("The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright.")
word_counter = Counter()
for s in train_set:
    word_counter.update(s.split())

print(word_counter)
```

Gives

```
Counter({'is': 2, 'The': 2, 'blue.': 1, 'bright.': 1, 'sky': 1, 'sun': 1})
```

Or you can use `FreqDist` from nltk:

```
from nltk import FreqDist

train_set = ("The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright.")
word_dist = FreqDist()
for s in train_set:
    word_dist.update(s.split())

print(dict(word_dist))
```

Gives

```
{'blue.': 1, 'bright.': 1, 'is': 2, 'sky': 1, 'sun': 1, 'The': 2}
```