# Using the subprocess module in Python

Tags: python, module, subprocess

I have written this simple Python script that finds the current date and time:

```
import subprocess 
time = subprocess.Popen('date')
print 'It is ', str(time)
```

When I run the program, I get the following:

```
It is  <subprocess.Popen object at 0x106fe6ad0>
Tue May 24 17:55:45 CEST 2016
```

How can I get rid of this part in the output? `<subprocess.Popen object at 0x106fe6ad0>`

On the other hand, if I use `call()`, as follows:

```
from subprocess import call 
time = call('date')
print 'It is ', str(time)
```

I get:

```
Tue May 24 17:57:29 CEST 2016
It is  0
```

How can I get the `Tue May 24 17:57:29 CEST 2016` come in place of `0`. And, why do we get `0` in the first hand?

Thanks.

Comment: unrelated: `import time; print(time.ctime())`

Answer (score 2):

All you really need for a simple process such as calling `date` is `subprocess.check_output`. I pass in a list out of habit in the example below but it's not necessary here since you only have a single element/command; i.e. `date`.

```
time = subprocess.check_output(['date'])
```

or simply

```
time = subprocess.check_output('date')
```

Putting it together:

```
import subprocess
time = subprocess.check_output(['date'])
print 'It is', time
```

The list is necessary if you have multiple statement such as the executable name followed by command line arguments. For instance, if you wanted `date` to display the UNIX epoch, you couldn't pass in the string `"date +%s"` but would have to use `["date", "+%s"]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `communicate` and `PIPE` to get the output:

```
import subprocess 

time = subprocess.Popen('date', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

output, errors = time.communicate()

print ('It is ', output.decode('utf-8').strip())
```

With `subprocess.call()`, `0` is the return value. `0` means that there was no error in executing the command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The output using your script is: ('It is ', u'Tue May 24 18:20:05 CEST 2016'). Why do I get the 'u'?

Comment: I believe the "print" statement can be simply be as follows? print 'It is', output

Comment: @Simplicity the 'u'  means [unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string)