# Split values and store into a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below python script:

```
conn=boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-1")
result=collections.defaultdict(list)
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
for res in reservations:
        for inst in res.instances:
                if 'clusters' in inst.tags:
                        values = inst.tags['clusters']
                        print values
```

and the output is:

```
baka-alpha,baka-beta
app
app-demo,dhivart
api
sahar-du,app,api
```

I want to store each value in a list as:

```
['baka-alpha', 'baka-beta', 'app', 'app-demo', 'dhivart', 'api', 'sahar-du', 'app', 'api']
```

How can I do so? Please let me know.

Comment: It didn't add any characters. Those characters just mean that the text is in unicode. Here is the [a related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string).

Comment: oh, nice to know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string that you want to split is already present in a variable, like `values`, you could try the following:

```
vl_list = [] # create a list for values
for line in values.split("\n"):
    vl_list.extend(line.split(","))
```

After this is complete, you'll have your values in a list `vl_list`

If the string is being read from stdin and you don't know, how many lines will be provided, you could do this instead:

```
from sys import stdin
vl_list = []
for line in stdin.readlines():
    vl_list.extend(line.split(","))
```

EDIT:
Your variable `values` does not contain all the values after the loop. So you can insert the splitting part straight into the loop and you'll get everything

```
vl_list = []
conn=boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-1")
result=collections.defaultdict(list)
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
for res in reservations:
        for inst in res.instances:
                if 'clusters' in inst.tags:
                        values = inst.tags['clusters']
                        vl_list.extend(values.split(","))
                        print values
```

Comment: I am getting multiple None as output

Comment: above output is stored in a variable named values. I need to store the values in list as [baka-alpha, baka-beta, app, app-demo, dhivart, api, sahar-du, app, api]

Comment: @SJJ What is the type of your variable `values`? You can check it by printing `type(values)`. Make sure it is a string. Also, try printing `repr(values)` and check if you get this printed: `'baka-alpha,baka-beta\napp\napp-demo,dhivart\napi\nsahar-du,app,api'`. This is how it should be stored. Because the above code works for me. [Here](http://ideone.com/OGuEVA) is the link to the online compiler that shows the code in action

Comment: printing `type(values)` returns **<type 'unicode'>** & `repr(values)` returns like **u'baka-alpha,baka-beta'**, then new line, then **u'app'**

Comment: @SJJ That is weird. Could you edit the question to show exactly how do you get the content of `values`?

Comment: @SJJ Take a look at the answer

Comment: Great! It worked liked a charm. Thank you so much! I just had to modify `values = str(inst.tags['clusters'])` and bring `print vl_list` out of loop. That's all!