# How to read text file columns to apply python data frame?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a Original **text file**: original.txt

```
tmin,       tmax,     mean, fmin, fmax, stdev
0,        0.005000,    0,     0,    0,    0
0.005000, 0.010000,    0,     0,    0,    0
```

For calculating, I read this file as CSV

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>import numpy as np
>>>from pandas import Series, DataFrame

>>>df=pd.read_csv('oringinal.txt')
>>>df 
      tmin   tmax   mean   fmin   fmax   stdev
0    0.000  0.005      0      0      0       0
1    0.005  0.010      0      0      0       0
```

When I enter **df.columns**

> Index([u'tmin', u' tmax', u' mean', u' fmin', u' fmax', u' stdev'], dtype='object')

What is **u'**? and 
I want to get some value from df.tmin[0], df.tmax[0], df.mean[0], df.fmin[0], df.fmax[0], df.stdev[0]... etc

**When I enter df.tmax[0], below error occurs.**

```
>>>df.tmax[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1947, in __getattr__
(type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tmax'
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: that basically means that you cannot access columns like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string

Comment: It's because the column name has a leading space: `u' tmax'`. You can access the column with `df[' tmax']` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are spaces in your column names:

```
Index([u'tmin', u' tmax', u' mean', u' fmin', u' fmax', u' stdev'], dtype='object')
```

By default `read_csv` parses the file using commas as the delimiter between fields. 
So `df` ends up with a column named `u' tmax'` instead of `u'tmax'`, for instance.

To parse the file correctly, use

```
df = pd.read_csv('oringinal.txt', sep=r',\s*')
```

instead. The regex pattern `,\s*` matches a literal comma followed by 0-or-more whitespace characters.

Notice that now the column names do not include spaces:

```
In [117]: df.columns
Out[117]: Index(['tmin', 'tmax', 'mean', 'fmin', 'fmax', 'stdev'], dtype='object')
```

---

`u'...'` is Python2's way of representing of a [unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string).

---

As UMax points out in [a now deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37948344/190597), alternatively you could use

```
df = pd.read_csv('oringinal.txt', skipinitialspace=True)
```

This avoids using regex pattern for the delimiter. Since regex is only supported by the `'python'` (parser) engine, and the `'c'` engine (which understands the `skipinitialspace=True`) is faster, UMax's alternative should be faster, especially for large files.

Answer (score 0):

The u' indicates unicode string.

To get the values of tmin, tmax etc, just enter

```
df.tmin
```

for entire column or

```
df['tmin']
```

You can get specific values by doing the following:

```
df.tmin[0]
```

or

```
df['tmin'][0]
```