# Trying to Remove the First 3 and Last 6 Characters from Each Item in a List

Tags: python, python-requests

This code pulls a little bit of data from RottenTomatoes. (Movie titles and tomato scores.) I'd like to now remove the the last 6 and first 3 characters from each item so only the movie title remains. I know that what I'm trying now would only remove the numbers if it worked.
I don't know if what I'm trying is in the ballpark but it's saying I have a tuple when I thought I had a list so it may be more complicated than I understand.

Example of what I have...

```
[(u'Ouija: Origin of Evil', 82), (u'Long Way North (Tout en haut du
monde)', 98), (u'Come And Find Me', 67), (u'My Father, Die', 78),
(u"Roger Corman's Death Race 2050", 100), ...
```

What I'd like done to it (as a permanent change to the list & not just printed in a new way)...

```
[Ouija: Origin of Evil, Long Way North (Tout en haut du monde), Come
And Find Me, My Father, Die, Roger Corman's Death Race 2050"...
```

My code...

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/'
                 'browse?page=1&limit=30&type=dvd-top-rentals&'
                 'services=amazon%3Bamazon_prime%3Bfandango_now%'
                 '3Bhbo_go%3Bitunes%3Bnetflix_iw%3Bvudu&sortBy=popularity')

movies = []
data = r.json()
for result in data["results"]:
    movies.append((result["title"], result["tomatoScore"]))

list2 = [i for i in movies if i[1] >=60]
list2 = ' '.join(list2).replace('1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9','').split()

print list2
```

The error...

```
(venv) My-MacBook-Pro:tor Me$ python bs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bs.py", line 16, in <module>
    list2 = ' '.join(list2).replace('1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9','').split()
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found
(venv) My-MacBook-Pro:tor Me$
```

Comment: You have a list of tuples. I think you just want `[t[0] for t in list2]`

Comment: Are you referring to the  " (u' " in the result? You stored the data as a list of tuples, and as a string in it, python prints that. It refers to unicode. For reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the first item in each tuple contained in the list, like so:

```
>>> mylist = [
    (u'Ouija: Origin of Evil', 82),
    (u'Long Way North (Tout en haut dumonde)', 98),
    (u'Come And Find Me', 67), (u'My Father, Die', 78),
    (u"Roger Corman's Death Race 2050", 100) ]
>>> result = [i[0] for i in mylist]
>>> print result
>>> ['Ouija: Origin of Evil', 'Long Way North (Tout en haut dumonde)', 'Come And Find Me', 'My Father, Die', "Roger Corman's Death Race 2050"]
```

Comment: Sounds like there are non-ascii unicode characters in some of the data your are processing. I used str() in the list comprehension to try return a "nicely printable" string but, to be honest, it probably isn't necessary. I modified my example to remove it. The leading u before each string simply indicates that it is a unicode string.

Comment: It was some title with weird characters. If you run the code & pull the data from RottenTomatoes.com you'll see it's position [9]. I deleted it and I deleted my comment asking you about it.
Thank you for pointing out the title and number were different items. I learned a lot here.