# How I take my modified JSON list and export it to CSV?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I wrote a Python script. It has an `untrusted` variable with this in it:

```
[{'id': 42042052, 'name': 'Lyft', 'package': 'com.abtutorial10.canadalyft5', 'uname': 'com-abtutorial10-canadalyft5', 'size': 2342327, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsdally/85767fc7ff03601ce1325fdedd9cf0dd_icon.png', 'graphic': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsdally/f0687693ea3eb5116894509683fa3f9d_fgraphic_705x345.jpg', 'added': '2018-11-23 15:23:47', 'modified': '2018-11-23 15:23:47', 'updated': '2018-11-23 15:23:47', 'uptype': 'regular', 'store': {'id': 2327139, 'name': 'appsdally', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsdally/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 66, 'subscribers': 4, 'downloads': 4472}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1', 'vercode': 2, 'md5sum': '06ae32afa8d57b9a3fc19f24e658898f', 'filesize': 2342327, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/appsdally/com-abtutorial10-canadalyft5-2-42042052-06ae32afa8d57b9a3fc19f24e658898f.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/appsdally/alt/Y29tLWFidHV0b3JpYWwxMC1jYW5hZGFseWZ0NS0yLTQyMDQyMDUyLTA2YWUzMmFmYThkNTdiOWEzZmMxOWYyNGU2NTg4OThm.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 7, 'pdownloads': 15, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 42033673, 'name': 'Lyft', 'package': 'com.abtutorial10.canadalyft4', 'uname': 'com-abtutorial10-canadalyft4', 'size': 2342311, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps0007/85767fc7ff03601ce1325fdedd9cf0dd_icon.png', 'graphic': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps0007/f0687693ea3eb5116894509683fa3f9d_fgraphic_705x345.jpg', 'added': '2018-11-23 05:42:04', 'modified': '2018-11-23 05:42:05', 'updated': '2018-11-23 05:42:05', 'uptype': 'regular', 'store': {'id': 2273010, 'name': 'apps0007', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps0007/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'pink', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 218, 'subscribers': 65, 'downloads': 71922}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1', 'vercode': 2, 'md5sum': '5a26e3c55946ba221b0dd041fee927f8', 'filesize': 2342311, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/apps0007/com-abtutorial10-canadalyft4-2-42033673-5a26e3c55946ba221b0dd041fee927f8.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/apps0007/alt/Y29tLWFidHV0b3JpYWwxMC1jYW5hZGFseWZ0NC0yLTQyMDMzNjczLTVhMjZlM2M1NTk0NmJhMjIxYjBkZDA0MWZlZTkyN2Y4.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 46, 'pdownloads': 46, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 41878039, 'name': 'Lyft', 'package': 'com.abtutorial10.canadalyft', 'uname': 'com-abtutorial10-canadalyft', 'size': 2342303, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsstoremarket/85767fc7ff03601ce1325fdedd9cf0dd_icon.png', 'graphic': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsstoremarket/f0687693ea3eb5116894509683fa3f9d_fgraphic_705x345.jpg', 'added': '2018-11-16 06:58:24', 'modified': '2018-11-16 06:58:24', 'updated': '2018-11-16 06:58:24', 'uptype': 'regular', 'store': {'id': 2122330, 'name': 'appsstoremarket', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsstoremarket/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 345, 'subscribers': 162, 'downloads': 156669}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1', 'vercode': 2, 'md5sum': 'ad47c17dc87d9f50d0cebd4fc71c3542', 'filesize': 2342303, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/appsstoremarket/com-abtutorial10-canadalyft-2-41878039-ad47c17dc87d9f50d0cebd4fc71c3542.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/appsstoremarket/alt/Y29tLWFidHV0b3JpYWwxMC1jYW5hZGFseWZ0LTItNDE4NzgwMzktYWQ0N2MxN2RjODdkOWY1MGQwY2ViZDRmYzcxYzM1NDI.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 27, 'pdownloads': 27, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 41989617, 'name': 'Lyft', 'package': 'com.abtutorial10.canadalyft2', 'uname': 'com-abtutorial10-canadalyft2', 'size': 2342287, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps018/85767fc7ff03601ce1325fdedd9cf0dd_icon.png', 'graphic': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps018/f0687693ea3eb5116894509683fa3f9d_fgraphic_705x345.jpg', 'added': '2018-11-21 08:04:06', 'modified': '2018-11-21 08:04:07', 'updated': '2018-11-21 08:04:07', 'uptype': 'regular', 'store': {'id': 2273237, 'name': 'apps018', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps018/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 176, 'subscribers': 38, 'downloads': 23996}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1', 'vercode': 2, 'md5sum': '0b4c234a748a6c42bb6c86f56787cf10', 'filesize': 2342287, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/apps018/com-abtutorial10-canadalyft2-2-41989617-0b4c234a748a6c42bb6c86f56787cf10.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/apps018/alt/Y29tLWFidHV0b3JpYWwxMC1jYW5hZGFseWZ0Mi0yLTQxOTg5NjE3LTBiNGMyMzRhNzQ4YTZjNDJiYjZjODZmNTY3ODdjZjEw.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 8, 'pdownloads': 8, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 41879202, 'name': 'Lyft', 'package': 'com.abtutorial10.canadalyft8', 'uname': 'com-abtutorial10-canadalyft8', 'size': 2342339, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/originalyes/85767fc7ff03601ce1325fdedd9cf0dd_icon.png', 'graphic': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/originalyes/c83abedbcad184c9f8ce6856dd63274e_fgraphic_705x345.jpg', 'added': '2018-11-16 08:37:55', 'modified': '2018-11-16 08:37:56', 'updated': '2018-11-16 08:37:56', 'uptype': 'regular', 'store': {'id': 2268473, 'name': 'originalyes', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/originalyes/da3bd21b288e5f980cc44ff6953fd9e5_ravatar.png', 'appearance': {'theme': 'pink', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 151, 'subscribers': 33, 'downloads': 25408}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1', 'vercode': 2, 'md5sum': 'd8c749ad0e7523c7887b029d52bc0411', 'filesize': 2342339, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/originalyes/com-abtutorial10-canadalyft8-2-41879202-d8c749ad0e7523c7887b029d52bc0411.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/originalyes/alt/Y29tLWFidHV0b3JpYWwxMC1jYW5hZGFseWZ0OC0yLTQxODc5MjAyLWQ4Yzc0OWFkMGU3NTIzYzc4ODdiMDI5ZDUyYmMwNDEx.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 7, 'pdownloads': 7, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 31174138, 'name': 'Surge Chaser for Lyft', 'package': 'com.uplyftprime', 'uname': 'surge-chaser-for-lyft', 'size': 9885571, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/devlindelfuego/6ae78524c53ca97c15c9b2befe58a3cc_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2017-08-06 08:23:23', 'modified': '2017-08-06 08:23:24', 'updated': '2017-08-06 08:23:24', 'uptype': 'aptbackup', 'store': {'id': 1618717, 'name': 'devlindelfuego', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/devlindelfuego/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 164, 'subscribers': 12, 'downloads': 3328}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.029', 'vercode': 30, 'md5sum': 'cc202eb8de4569095aec2f86b7265f94', 'filesize': 9885571, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/devlindelfuego/com-uplyftprime-30-31174138-cc202eb8de4569095aec2f86b7265f94.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/devlindelfuego/alt/Y29tLXVwbHlmdHByaW1lLTMwLTMxMTc0MTM4LWNjMjAyZWI4ZGU0NTY5MDk1YWVjMmY4NmI3MjY1Zjk0.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 10, 'pdownloads': 11, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': True, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 26296353, 'name': 'Lyft car hire', 'package': 'cc.snapp.app_lyft_car_hire', 'uname': 'lyft-car-hire', 'size': 49270686, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/snappbuilder/1a3e8d7ee63aee4ce41f4f09afc5eb6e.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2017-04-23 08:45:23', 'modified': '2017-04-23 08:45:23', 'updated': '2017-04-23 08:45:23', 'uptype': 'webservice', 'store': {'id': 992935, 'name': 'snappbuilder', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/snappbuilder/4fd67e18c3369c00e55d58854466d4fb_ravatar.png', 'appearance': {'theme': 'lightsky', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 11364, 'subscribers': 4879, 'downloads': 655515}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.9.2', 'vercode': 570313178, 'md5sum': 'a7475d8c27b7672f1020013847a8ea6e', 'filesize': 49270686, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/snappbuilder/cc-snapp-app-lyft-car-hire-570313178-26296353-a7475d8c27b7672f1020013847a8ea6e.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/snappbuilder/alt/Y2Mtc25hcHAtYXBwLWx5ZnQtY2FyLWhpcmUtNTcwMzEzMTc4LTI2Mjk2MzUzLWE3NDc1ZDhjMjdiNzY3MmYxMDIwMDEzODQ3YThlYTZl.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 2, 'pdownloads': 3, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 23145792, 'name': 'Assist4Lyft: Lyft Promo Codes', 'package': 'com.thelyftrider.lyftassist', 'uname': 'assist-4lyft', 'size': 5850532, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/vegasrome/199e862cf067a80d5ef93617ac7f14c8_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2017-01-28 11:53:43', 'modified': '2017-01-28 11:53:43', 'updated': '2018-02-06 01:12:25', 'uptype': 'aptuploader', 'store': {'id': 52879, 'name': 'vegasrome', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/vegasrome/3c9c3ea9ed74341c8a45890d6ea32fb3_ravatar.png', 'appearance': {'theme': 'black', 'description': 'Enjoy and keep in mind.. some of my uploads my require Lucky Patcher, Google Play Mod, and ROOT\r\nDo my best to bring you latest versions.'}, 'stats': {'apps': 8856, 'subscribers': 19216, 'downloads': 3672234}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.0', 'vercode': 1, 'md5sum': '817c42f6a997ef8bc60e54c61bbcfb71', 'filesize': 5850532, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/vegasrome/com-thelyftrider-lyftassist-1-23145792-817c42f6a997ef8bc60e54c61bbcfb71.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/vegasrome/alt/Y29tLXRoZWx5ZnRyaWRlci1seWZ0YXNzaXN0LTEtMjMxNDU3OTItODE3YzQyZjZhOTk3ZWY4YmM2MGU1NGM2MWJiY2ZiNzE.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 29, 'pdownloads': 30, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 21730958, 'name': 'FareWell', 'package': 'com.farewell', 'uname': 'robert-niimi-farewell', 'size': 8932627, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/yupofcourse/31d67d608e150feb9ab632c9be86d482_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2016-11-08 04:49:30', 'modified': '2016-11-08 04:49:31', 'updated': '2017-01-28 11:50:44', 'uptype': 'aptbackup', 'store': {'id': 1077022, 'name': 'yupofcourse', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/yupofcourse/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'pink', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 2677, 'subscribers': 1792, 'downloads': 371478}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.0', 'vercode': 1, 'md5sum': 'e61d398585197b8ed0df2a08f79396b8', 'filesize': 8932627, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/yupofcourse/com-farewell-1-21730958-e61d398585197b8ed0df2a08f79396b8.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/yupofcourse/alt/Y29tLWZhcmV3ZWxsLTEtMjE3MzA5NTgtZTYxZDM5ODU4NTE5N2I4ZWQwZGYyYTA4Zjc5Mzk2Yjg.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 30, 'pdownloads': 30, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 39440400, 'name': 'Free Taxi Coupons For Lyft', 'package': 'com.pulsarappz.freetaxicouponsforlyft', 'uname': 'free-taxi-coupons-for-lyft', 'size': 5898638, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/e919b13803869a85bfc01a44bea9f854_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2018-08-09 05:58:07', 'modified': '2018-08-09 05:58:07', 'updated': '2018-08-09 05:58:07', 'uptype': 'aptuploader', 'store': {'id': 2173406, 'name': 'lm2442', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'black', 'description': 'Browns'}, 'stats': {'apps': 43, 'subscribers': 1, 'downloads': 68}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.9', 'vercode': 10, 'md5sum': 'a50e0aea81b50407bed88d1a46a8afed', 'filesize': 5898638, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/com-pulsarappz-freetaxicouponsforlyft-10-39440400-a50e0aea81b50407bed88d1a46a8afed.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/alt/Y29tLXB1bHNhcmFwcHotZnJlZXRheGljb3Vwb25zZm9ybHlmdC0xMC0zOTQ0MDQwMC1hNTBlMGFlYTgxYjUwNDA3YmVkODhkMWE0NmE4YWZlZA.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 8, 'pdownloads': 10, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}}, 'has_versions': True, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 18107829, 'name': 'Lyft Taxi Bus Alternative', 'package': 'net.krwkfy.lyft.taxi.bus.alternative', 'uname': 'krwkfy-lyft-taxi-alternative', 'size': 4205039, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/helenayzes/3d153d49aa7ddd882f95318bed089ad6.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2016-03-10 02:13:22', 'modified': '2016-03-10 02:13:22', 'updated': '2016-03-10 02:13:22', 'uptype': 'webservice', 'store': {'id': 949999, 'name': 'helenayzes', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/helenayzes/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 21, 'subscribers': 5, 'downloads': 2182}}, 'file': {'vername': '8.1.1008', 'vercode': 392145239, 'md5sum': '9ca5a51a6e7ba88465676201c25d1291', 'filesize': 4205039, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/helenayzes/net-krwkfy-lyft-taxi-bus-alternative-392145239-18107829-9ca5a51a6e7ba88465676201c25d1291.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/helenayzes/alt/bmV0LWtyd2tmeS1seWZ0LXRheGktYnVzLWFsdGVybmF0aXZlLTM5MjE0NTIzOS0xODEwNzgyOS05Y2E1YTUxYTZlN2JhODg0NjU2NzYyMDFjMjVkMTI5MQ.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 13, 'pdownloads': 13, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 23075890, 'name': 'Fare Compare Uber, Lyft & Taxi', 'package': 'com.zailoo.xroads', 'uname': 'goa2b', 'size': 8712680, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/moshkosh/afd317768d4e241c2f6b86dea7810464_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2017-01-21 09:30:00', 'modified': '2017-01-21 09:30:01', 'updated': '2017-04-18 04:00:55', 'uptype': 'aptbackup', 'store': {'id': 1128043, 'name': 'moshkosh', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/moshkosh/31d3c02ce8ddbeaa844ba1b0aa1d6cb2_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'light-blue', 'description': "Everything you want, Nothing you need.. \nOn a real note though, I upload the apps I frequent as well as the one timers I don't."}, 'stats': {'apps': 2333, 'subscribers': 165, 'downloads': 52338}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1.0', 'vercode': 10148, 'md5sum': 'fc91fbde809abb73e259563820aa2593', 'filesize': 8712680, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/moshkosh/com-zailoo-xroads-10148-23075890-fc91fbde809abb73e259563820aa2593.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/moshkosh/alt/Y29tLXphaWxvby14cm9hZHMtMTAxNDgtMjMwNzU4OTAtZmM5MWZiZGU4MDlhYmI3M2UyNTk1NjM4MjBhYTI1OTM.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 8, 'pdownloads': 10, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': True, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 5971395, 'name': 'lyft uber easy taxi cabs', 'package': 'thetaxiapp.com', 'uname': 'lyft-uber-easy-taxi-cabs', 'size': 3442701, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/shaddon-green/ecb0e8b1ce78b612c06288cb194d6818_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2014-06-04 06:38:56', 'modified': '2014-06-04 06:38:56', 'updated': '2014-06-04 06:38:56', 'uptype': 'aptbackup', 'store': {'id': 120645, 'name': 'shaddon-green', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/shaddon-green/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'indigo', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 1255, 'subscribers': 697, 'downloads': 115051}}, 'file': {'vername': '6.1.0.0.14', 'vercode': 177, 'md5sum': 'edddd6358e0c60b15caef4322341d3ff', 'filesize': 3442701, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/shaddon-green/thetaxiapp-com-177-5971395-edddd6358e0c60b15caef4322341d3ff.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/shaddon-green/alt/dGhldGF4aWFwcC1jb20tMTc3LTU5NzEzOTUtZWRkZGQ2MzU4ZTBjNjBiMTVjYWVmNDMyMjM0MWQzZmY.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 303, 'pdownloads': 294, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 2}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 2}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 37966226, 'name': 'Free Taxi Ride Coupons for Lyft', 'package': 'com.appfactory.taxicouponslyft', 'uname': 'taxi-coupons-lyft', 'size': 4902371, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/vivo-api/699da34f6b1cede35beda1f20ffa600d_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2018-06-08 02:22:53', 'modified': '2018-06-08 02:22:53', 'updated': '2018-06-08 02:22:53', 'uptype': 'webservice', 'store': {'id': 1463246, 'name': 'vivo-api', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/vivo-api/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 123417, 'subscribers': 6878, 'downloads': 4220618}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.2', 'vercode': 3, 'md5sum': 'a7fcb7844b897b95d2f8fd9dae6d716d', 'filesize': 4902371, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/vivo-api/com-appfactory-taxicouponslyft-3-37966226-a7fcb7844b897b95d2f8fd9dae6d716d.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/vivo-api/alt/Y29tLWFwcGZhY3RvcnktdGF4aWNvdXBvbnNseWZ0LTMtMzc5NjYyMjYtYTdmY2I3ODQ0Yjg5N2I5NWQyZjhmZDlkYWU2ZDcxNmQ.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 8, 'pdownloads': 8, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 38283734, 'name': 'Free Ride Promos for Lyft Cab', 'package': 'com.shineappzz.newlyftcoupons', 'uname': 'newlyftcoupons-big-shine-team', 'size': 4217943, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/legacyapps13/1d630b774f661acaace44e9f54f43f71_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2018-06-20 16:23:24', 'modified': '2018-06-20 16:23:24', 'updated': '2018-06-20 16:23:24', 'uptype': 'aptuploader', 'store': {'id': 2025398, 'name': 'legacyapps13', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/legacyapps13/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 84, 'subscribers': 44, 'downloads': 19482}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.0', 'vercode': 1, 'md5sum': 'b6df2843e8025eac0b10853f1af3fcb6', 'filesize': 4217943, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/legacyapps13/com-shineappzz-newlyftcoupons-1-38283734-b6df2843e8025eac0b10853f1af3fcb6.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/legacyapps13/alt/Y29tLXNoaW5lYXBwenotbmV3bHlmdGNvdXBvbnMtMS0zODI4MzczNC1iNmRmMjg0M2U4MDI1ZWFjMGIxMDg1M2YxYWYzZmNiNg.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 3, 'pdownloads': 3, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 39440422, 'name': 'Taxi Coupons for Lyft  - Canada & USA', 'package': 'com.pulsarappz.couponsforlyft_usandcanada', 'uname': 'coupons-for-lyft-us-and-canada', 'size': 6186897, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/f561c396db660e6989ea894953166976_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2018-08-09 05:59:09', 'modified': '2018-08-09 05:59:10', 'updated': '2018-08-09 05:59:10', 'uptype': 'aptuploader', 'store': {'id': 2173406, 'name': 'lm2442', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'black', 'description': 'Browns'}, 'stats': {'apps': 43, 'subscribers': 1, 'downloads': 68}}, 'file': {'vername': '5.0', 'vercode': 5, 'md5sum': 'afc9cb352de940d11b5e0a1437261d4c', 'filesize': 6186897, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/com-pulsarappz-couponsforlyft-usandcanada-5-39440422-afc9cb352de940d11b5e0a1437261d4c.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/alt/Y29tLXB1bHNhcmFwcHotY291cG9uc2Zvcmx5ZnQtdXNhbmRjYW5hZGEtNS0zOTQ0MDQyMi1hZmM5Y2IzNTJkZTk0MGQxMWI1ZTBhMTQzNzI2MWQ0Yw.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 2, 'pdownloads': 2, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}]
```

How do I take `untrusted` and export it to my CSV file, `new_csv`, in the proper CSV format?

Comment: what does that mean, `untrusted` variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting-a-json-list-to-csv-file-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780430/converting-a-json-list-to-csv-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to convert that to dataframe, you can use json_normalize. Then take that dataframe and save as csv.

```
data = [{'id': 42042052, 'name': 'Lyft', 'package': 'com.abtutorial10.canadalyft5', 'uname': 'com-abtutorial10-canadalyft5', 'size': 2342327, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsdally/85767fc7ff03601ce1325fdedd9cf0dd_icon.png', 'graphic': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsdally/f0687693ea3eb5116894509683fa3f9d_fgraphic_705x345.jpg', 'added': '2018-11-23 15:23:47', 'modified': '2018-11-23 15:23:47', 'updated': '2018-11-23 15:23:47', 'uptype': 'regular', 'store': {'id': 2327139, 'name': 'appsdally', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsdally/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 66, 'subscribers': 4, 'downloads': 4472}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1', 'vercode': 2, 'md5sum': '06ae32afa8d57b9a3fc19f24e658898f', 'filesize': 2342327, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/appsdally/com-abtutorial10-canadalyft5-2-42042052-06ae32afa8d57b9a3fc19f24e658898f.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/appsdally/alt/Y29tLWFidHV0b3JpYWwxMC1jYW5hZGFseWZ0NS0yLTQyMDQyMDUyLTA2YWUzMmFmYThkNTdiOWEzZmMxOWYyNGU2NTg4OThm.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 7, 'pdownloads': 15, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 42033673, 'name': 'Lyft', 'package': 'com.abtutorial10.canadalyft4', 'uname': 'com-abtutorial10-canadalyft4', 'size': 2342311, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps0007/85767fc7ff03601ce1325fdedd9cf0dd_icon.png', 'graphic': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps0007/f0687693ea3eb5116894509683fa3f9d_fgraphic_705x345.jpg', 'added': '2018-11-23 05:42:04', 'modified': '2018-11-23 05:42:05', 'updated': '2018-11-23 05:42:05', 'uptype': 'regular', 'store': {'id': 2273010, 'name': 'apps0007', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps0007/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'pink', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 218, 'subscribers': 65, 'downloads': 71922}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1', 'vercode': 2, 'md5sum': '5a26e3c55946ba221b0dd041fee927f8', 'filesize': 2342311, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/apps0007/com-abtutorial10-canadalyft4-2-42033673-5a26e3c55946ba221b0dd041fee927f8.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/apps0007/alt/Y29tLWFidHV0b3JpYWwxMC1jYW5hZGFseWZ0NC0yLTQyMDMzNjczLTVhMjZlM2M1NTk0NmJhMjIxYjBkZDA0MWZlZTkyN2Y4.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 46, 'pdownloads': 46, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 41878039, 'name': 'Lyft', 'package': 'com.abtutorial10.canadalyft', 'uname': 'com-abtutorial10-canadalyft', 'size': 2342303, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsstoremarket/85767fc7ff03601ce1325fdedd9cf0dd_icon.png', 'graphic': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsstoremarket/f0687693ea3eb5116894509683fa3f9d_fgraphic_705x345.jpg', 'added': '2018-11-16 06:58:24', 'modified': '2018-11-16 06:58:24', 'updated': '2018-11-16 06:58:24', 'uptype': 'regular', 'store': {'id': 2122330, 'name': 'appsstoremarket', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/appsstoremarket/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 345, 'subscribers': 162, 'downloads': 156669}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1', 'vercode': 2, 'md5sum': 'ad47c17dc87d9f50d0cebd4fc71c3542', 'filesize': 2342303, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/appsstoremarket/com-abtutorial10-canadalyft-2-41878039-ad47c17dc87d9f50d0cebd4fc71c3542.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/appsstoremarket/alt/Y29tLWFidHV0b3JpYWwxMC1jYW5hZGFseWZ0LTItNDE4NzgwMzktYWQ0N2MxN2RjODdkOWY1MGQwY2ViZDRmYzcxYzM1NDI.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 27, 'pdownloads': 27, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 41989617, 'name': 'Lyft', 'package': 'com.abtutorial10.canadalyft2', 'uname': 'com-abtutorial10-canadalyft2', 'size': 2342287, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps018/85767fc7ff03601ce1325fdedd9cf0dd_icon.png', 'graphic': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps018/f0687693ea3eb5116894509683fa3f9d_fgraphic_705x345.jpg', 'added': '2018-11-21 08:04:06', 'modified': '2018-11-21 08:04:07', 'updated': '2018-11-21 08:04:07', 'uptype': 'regular', 'store': {'id': 2273237, 'name': 'apps018', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/apps018/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 176, 'subscribers': 38, 'downloads': 23996}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1', 'vercode': 2, 'md5sum': '0b4c234a748a6c42bb6c86f56787cf10', 'filesize': 2342287, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/apps018/com-abtutorial10-canadalyft2-2-41989617-0b4c234a748a6c42bb6c86f56787cf10.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/apps018/alt/Y29tLWFidHV0b3JpYWwxMC1jYW5hZGFseWZ0Mi0yLTQxOTg5NjE3LTBiNGMyMzRhNzQ4YTZjNDJiYjZjODZmNTY3ODdjZjEw.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 8, 'pdownloads': 8, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 41879202, 'name': 'Lyft', 'package': 'com.abtutorial10.canadalyft8', 'uname': 'com-abtutorial10-canadalyft8', 'size': 2342339, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/originalyes/85767fc7ff03601ce1325fdedd9cf0dd_icon.png', 'graphic': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/originalyes/c83abedbcad184c9f8ce6856dd63274e_fgraphic_705x345.jpg', 'added': '2018-11-16 08:37:55', 'modified': '2018-11-16 08:37:56', 'updated': '2018-11-16 08:37:56', 'uptype': 'regular', 'store': {'id': 2268473, 'name': 'originalyes', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/originalyes/da3bd21b288e5f980cc44ff6953fd9e5_ravatar.png', 'appearance': {'theme': 'pink', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 151, 'subscribers': 33, 'downloads': 25408}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1', 'vercode': 2, 'md5sum': 'd8c749ad0e7523c7887b029d52bc0411', 'filesize': 2342339, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/originalyes/com-abtutorial10-canadalyft8-2-41879202-d8c749ad0e7523c7887b029d52bc0411.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/originalyes/alt/Y29tLWFidHV0b3JpYWwxMC1jYW5hZGFseWZ0OC0yLTQxODc5MjAyLWQ4Yzc0OWFkMGU3NTIzYzc4ODdiMDI5ZDUyYmMwNDEx.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 7, 'pdownloads': 7, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 31174138, 'name': 'Surge Chaser for Lyft', 'package': 'com.uplyftprime', 'uname': 'surge-chaser-for-lyft', 'size': 9885571, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/devlindelfuego/6ae78524c53ca97c15c9b2befe58a3cc_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2017-08-06 08:23:23', 'modified': '2017-08-06 08:23:24', 'updated': '2017-08-06 08:23:24', 'uptype': 'aptbackup', 'store': {'id': 1618717, 'name': 'devlindelfuego', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/devlindelfuego/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 164, 'subscribers': 12, 'downloads': 3328}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.029', 'vercode': 30, 'md5sum': 'cc202eb8de4569095aec2f86b7265f94', 'filesize': 9885571, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/devlindelfuego/com-uplyftprime-30-31174138-cc202eb8de4569095aec2f86b7265f94.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/devlindelfuego/alt/Y29tLXVwbHlmdHByaW1lLTMwLTMxMTc0MTM4LWNjMjAyZWI4ZGU0NTY5MDk1YWVjMmY4NmI3MjY1Zjk0.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 10, 'pdownloads': 11, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': True, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 26296353, 'name': 'Lyft car hire', 'package': 'cc.snapp.app_lyft_car_hire', 'uname': 'lyft-car-hire', 'size': 49270686, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/snappbuilder/1a3e8d7ee63aee4ce41f4f09afc5eb6e.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2017-04-23 08:45:23', 'modified': '2017-04-23 08:45:23', 'updated': '2017-04-23 08:45:23', 'uptype': 'webservice', 'store': {'id': 992935, 'name': 'snappbuilder', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/snappbuilder/4fd67e18c3369c00e55d58854466d4fb_ravatar.png', 'appearance': {'theme': 'lightsky', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 11364, 'subscribers': 4879, 'downloads': 655515}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.9.2', 'vercode': 570313178, 'md5sum': 'a7475d8c27b7672f1020013847a8ea6e', 'filesize': 49270686, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/snappbuilder/cc-snapp-app-lyft-car-hire-570313178-26296353-a7475d8c27b7672f1020013847a8ea6e.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/snappbuilder/alt/Y2Mtc25hcHAtYXBwLWx5ZnQtY2FyLWhpcmUtNTcwMzEzMTc4LTI2Mjk2MzUzLWE3NDc1ZDhjMjdiNzY3MmYxMDIwMDEzODQ3YThlYTZl.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 2, 'pdownloads': 3, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 23145792, 'name': 'Assist4Lyft: Lyft Promo Codes', 'package': 'com.thelyftrider.lyftassist', 'uname': 'assist-4lyft', 'size': 5850532, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/vegasrome/199e862cf067a80d5ef93617ac7f14c8_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2017-01-28 11:53:43', 'modified': '2017-01-28 11:53:43', 'updated': '2018-02-06 01:12:25', 'uptype': 'aptuploader', 'store': {'id': 52879, 'name': 'vegasrome', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/vegasrome/3c9c3ea9ed74341c8a45890d6ea32fb3_ravatar.png', 'appearance': {'theme': 'black', 'description': 'Enjoy and keep in mind.. some of my uploads my require Lucky Patcher, Google Play Mod, and ROOT\r\nDo my best to bring you latest versions.'}, 'stats': {'apps': 8856, 'subscribers': 19216, 'downloads': 3672234}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.0', 'vercode': 1, 'md5sum': '817c42f6a997ef8bc60e54c61bbcfb71', 'filesize': 5850532, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/vegasrome/com-thelyftrider-lyftassist-1-23145792-817c42f6a997ef8bc60e54c61bbcfb71.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/vegasrome/alt/Y29tLXRoZWx5ZnRyaWRlci1seWZ0YXNzaXN0LTEtMjMxNDU3OTItODE3YzQyZjZhOTk3ZWY4YmM2MGU1NGM2MWJiY2ZiNzE.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 29, 'pdownloads': 30, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 21730958, 'name': 'FareWell', 'package': 'com.farewell', 'uname': 'robert-niimi-farewell', 'size': 8932627, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/yupofcourse/31d67d608e150feb9ab632c9be86d482_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2016-11-08 04:49:30', 'modified': '2016-11-08 04:49:31', 'updated': '2017-01-28 11:50:44', 'uptype': 'aptbackup', 'store': {'id': 1077022, 'name': 'yupofcourse', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/yupofcourse/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'pink', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 2677, 'subscribers': 1792, 'downloads': 371478}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.0', 'vercode': 1, 'md5sum': 'e61d398585197b8ed0df2a08f79396b8', 'filesize': 8932627, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/yupofcourse/com-farewell-1-21730958-e61d398585197b8ed0df2a08f79396b8.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/yupofcourse/alt/Y29tLWZhcmV3ZWxsLTEtMjE3MzA5NTgtZTYxZDM5ODU4NTE5N2I4ZWQwZGYyYTA4Zjc5Mzk2Yjg.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 30, 'pdownloads': 30, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 39440400, 'name': 'Free Taxi Coupons For Lyft', 'package': 'com.pulsarappz.freetaxicouponsforlyft', 'uname': 'free-taxi-coupons-for-lyft', 'size': 5898638, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/e919b13803869a85bfc01a44bea9f854_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2018-08-09 05:58:07', 'modified': '2018-08-09 05:58:07', 'updated': '2018-08-09 05:58:07', 'uptype': 'aptuploader', 'store': {'id': 2173406, 'name': 'lm2442', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'black', 'description': 'Browns'}, 'stats': {'apps': 43, 'subscribers': 1, 'downloads': 68}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.9', 'vercode': 10, 'md5sum': 'a50e0aea81b50407bed88d1a46a8afed', 'filesize': 5898638, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/com-pulsarappz-freetaxicouponsforlyft-10-39440400-a50e0aea81b50407bed88d1a46a8afed.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/alt/Y29tLXB1bHNhcmFwcHotZnJlZXRheGljb3Vwb25zZm9ybHlmdC0xMC0zOTQ0MDQwMC1hNTBlMGFlYTgxYjUwNDA3YmVkODhkMWE0NmE4YWZlZA.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 8, 'pdownloads': 10, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}}, 'has_versions': True, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 18107829, 'name': 'Lyft Taxi Bus Alternative', 'package': 'net.krwkfy.lyft.taxi.bus.alternative', 'uname': 'krwkfy-lyft-taxi-alternative', 'size': 4205039, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/helenayzes/3d153d49aa7ddd882f95318bed089ad6.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2016-03-10 02:13:22', 'modified': '2016-03-10 02:13:22', 'updated': '2016-03-10 02:13:22', 'uptype': 'webservice', 'store': {'id': 949999, 'name': 'helenayzes', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/helenayzes/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 21, 'subscribers': 5, 'downloads': 2182}}, 'file': {'vername': '8.1.1008', 'vercode': 392145239, 'md5sum': '9ca5a51a6e7ba88465676201c25d1291', 'filesize': 4205039, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/helenayzes/net-krwkfy-lyft-taxi-bus-alternative-392145239-18107829-9ca5a51a6e7ba88465676201c25d1291.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/helenayzes/alt/bmV0LWtyd2tmeS1seWZ0LXRheGktYnVzLWFsdGVybmF0aXZlLTM5MjE0NTIzOS0xODEwNzgyOS05Y2E1YTUxYTZlN2JhODg0NjU2NzYyMDFjMjVkMTI5MQ.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 13, 'pdownloads': 13, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 23075890, 'name': 'Fare Compare Uber, Lyft & Taxi', 'package': 'com.zailoo.xroads', 'uname': 'goa2b', 'size': 8712680, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/moshkosh/afd317768d4e241c2f6b86dea7810464_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2017-01-21 09:30:00', 'modified': '2017-01-21 09:30:01', 'updated': '2017-04-18 04:00:55', 'uptype': 'aptbackup', 'store': {'id': 1128043, 'name': 'moshkosh', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/moshkosh/31d3c02ce8ddbeaa844ba1b0aa1d6cb2_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'light-blue', 'description': "Everything you want, Nothing you need.. \nOn a real note though, I upload the apps I frequent as well as the one timers I don't."}, 'stats': {'apps': 2333, 'subscribers': 165, 'downloads': 52338}}, 'file': {'vername': '2.1.0', 'vercode': 10148, 'md5sum': 'fc91fbde809abb73e259563820aa2593', 'filesize': 8712680, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/moshkosh/com-zailoo-xroads-10148-23075890-fc91fbde809abb73e259563820aa2593.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/moshkosh/alt/Y29tLXphaWxvby14cm9hZHMtMTAxNDgtMjMwNzU4OTAtZmM5MWZiZGU4MDlhYmI3M2UyNTk1NjM4MjBhYTI1OTM.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 8, 'pdownloads': 10, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': True, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 5971395, 'name': 'lyft uber easy taxi cabs', 'package': 'thetaxiapp.com', 'uname': 'lyft-uber-easy-taxi-cabs', 'size': 3442701, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/shaddon-green/ecb0e8b1ce78b612c06288cb194d6818_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2014-06-04 06:38:56', 'modified': '2014-06-04 06:38:56', 'updated': '2014-06-04 06:38:56', 'uptype': 'aptbackup', 'store': {'id': 120645, 'name': 'shaddon-green', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/shaddon-green/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'indigo', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 1255, 'subscribers': 697, 'downloads': 115051}}, 'file': {'vername': '6.1.0.0.14', 'vercode': 177, 'md5sum': 'edddd6358e0c60b15caef4322341d3ff', 'filesize': 3442701, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/shaddon-green/thetaxiapp-com-177-5971395-edddd6358e0c60b15caef4322341d3ff.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/shaddon-green/alt/dGhldGF4aWFwcC1jb20tMTc3LTU5NzEzOTUtZWRkZGQ2MzU4ZTBjNjBiMTVjYWVmNDMyMjM0MWQzZmY.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 303, 'pdownloads': 294, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 2}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 2}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 37966226, 'name': 'Free Taxi Ride Coupons for Lyft', 'package': 'com.appfactory.taxicouponslyft', 'uname': 'taxi-coupons-lyft', 'size': 4902371, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/vivo-api/699da34f6b1cede35beda1f20ffa600d_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2018-06-08 02:22:53', 'modified': '2018-06-08 02:22:53', 'updated': '2018-06-08 02:22:53', 'uptype': 'webservice', 'store': {'id': 1463246, 'name': 'vivo-api', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/vivo-api/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 123417, 'subscribers': 6878, 'downloads': 4220618}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.2', 'vercode': 3, 'md5sum': 'a7fcb7844b897b95d2f8fd9dae6d716d', 'filesize': 4902371, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/vivo-api/com-appfactory-taxicouponslyft-3-37966226-a7fcb7844b897b95d2f8fd9dae6d716d.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/vivo-api/alt/Y29tLWFwcGZhY3RvcnktdGF4aWNvdXBvbnNseWZ0LTMtMzc5NjYyMjYtYTdmY2I3ODQ0Yjg5N2I5NWQyZjhmZDlkYWU2ZDcxNmQ.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 8, 'pdownloads': 8, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 38283734, 'name': 'Free Ride Promos for Lyft Cab', 'package': 'com.shineappzz.newlyftcoupons', 'uname': 'newlyftcoupons-big-shine-team', 'size': 4217943, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/legacyapps13/1d630b774f661acaace44e9f54f43f71_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2018-06-20 16:23:24', 'modified': '2018-06-20 16:23:24', 'updated': '2018-06-20 16:23:24', 'uptype': 'aptuploader', 'store': {'id': 2025398, 'name': 'legacyapps13', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/legacyapps13/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'default', 'description': ''}, 'stats': {'apps': 84, 'subscribers': 44, 'downloads': 19482}}, 'file': {'vername': '1.0', 'vercode': 1, 'md5sum': 'b6df2843e8025eac0b10853f1af3fcb6', 'filesize': 4217943, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/legacyapps13/com-shineappzz-newlyftcoupons-1-38283734-b6df2843e8025eac0b10853f1af3fcb6.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/legacyapps13/alt/Y29tLXNoaW5lYXBwenotbmV3bHlmdGNvdXBvbnMtMS0zODI4MzczNC1iNmRmMjg0M2U4MDI1ZWFjMGIxMDg1M2YxYWYzZmNiNg.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 3, 'pdownloads': 3, 'rating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}, 'prating': {'avg': 5, 'total': 1}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}, {'id': 39440422, 'name': 'Taxi Coupons for Lyft  - Canada & USA', 'package': 'com.pulsarappz.couponsforlyft_usandcanada', 'uname': 'coupons-for-lyft-us-and-canada', 'size': 6186897, 'icon': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/f561c396db660e6989ea894953166976_icon.png', 'graphic': None, 'added': '2018-08-09 05:59:09', 'modified': '2018-08-09 05:59:10', 'updated': '2018-08-09 05:59:10', 'uptype': 'aptuploader', 'store': {'id': 2173406, 'name': 'lm2442', 'avatar': 'http://pool.img.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/3bf5adf05843f9f28c486d5ddef8f873_ravatar.jpg', 'appearance': {'theme': 'black', 'description': 'Browns'}, 'stats': {'apps': 43, 'subscribers': 1, 'downloads': 68}}, 'file': {'vername': '5.0', 'vercode': 5, 'md5sum': 'afc9cb352de940d11b5e0a1437261d4c', 'filesize': 6186897, 'path': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/com-pulsarappz-couponsforlyft-usandcanada-5-39440422-afc9cb352de940d11b5e0a1437261d4c.apk', 'path_alt': 'http://pool.apk.xxxxxxx.com/lm2442/alt/Y29tLXB1bHNhcmFwcHotY291cG9uc2Zvcmx5ZnQtdXNhbmRjYW5hZGEtNS0zOTQ0MDQyMi1hZmM5Y2IzNTJkZTk0MGQxMWI1ZTBhMTQzNzI2MWQ0Yw.apk', 'malware': {'rank': 'UNKNOWN'}}, 'stats': {'downloads': 2, 'pdownloads': 2, 'rating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}, 'prating': {'avg': 0, 'total': 0}}, 'has_versions': False, 'obb': None, 'appcoins': {'advertising': False, 'billing': False}}]

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(data)

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to keep the columns in the same original order, and remove the spaces between each row?

Comment: 1) the data is a list of dictionaries. Dictionary keys don't inherently have an "order". But what you can do, is put the keys into a list and then re-define the dataframe with that list to say where your columns are. 2) what do you mean remove spaces between each row? There are now spaces between each row.

Comment: I'm a noob, so I'm having some trouble understanding the first one, although the column order isn't that important. And by row spaces, I mean that the solution you provided worked, but my csv file has an empty row between every two rows of data.

Comment: basically, you could take the keys and put them into a list. Then you could say `df = df[cols]`. The problem with doinf that is the keys in your json are nested, so it's not as simple as just creating a list, you'd need to sort of iterate or write a function to do it. Not the easiest thing, but not impossible. You could alternatively, just manually set the column order, but it's not robust, and if a new column pops up later, you could get an error.

Comment: I'll look at the rows now. I didn't notice it previously.

Comment: I just checked, the csv generated by the code above isn't showing any spaces between any rows. Not sure why thats showing for you. Maybe check to makes sure you have the latest Pandas version?

Comment: Just checked, I have Pandas 0.24.2