# Objects are not valid as a React child data from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, reactjs, flask

I'm working on a project that uses Flask as a backend and sends data from MongoDB database and sends it to React to print on the screen.
In the Flash file

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/post')
def post():
db = connection.posthub
cursor = db.post.find() //make the cursor 
return render_template('index.html', cursor = cursor) //render template index.html with cursor
```

In the pug file.

```
extends main

block content
| {% for post in cursor %}  //Interating cursor with post variable
#demo {{ post }} // sending post to demo for react to render
|{% endfor %}
```

In React file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class NewComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {myData:{}}
 }

componentDidMount(){
    console.log("Mounting Components")
    let data = document.getElementById('demo').InnerHTML; //getting data from html tag
    console.log(typeof(data));
    data = JSON.parse(data); // parse it
    this.setState({myData:data}); //set the state
 }

render(){
    return(
      <h3>{this.state.myData}</h3> //print it 
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <NewComponent />,
    document.getElementById('demo')
)
```

It's printing:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('597619b7c07b2dc30a108def'), u'description': u'hello', u'title': u'sankit'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('59761b2cc6568a4e341b6b89'), u'description': u'lets add some thing new', u'title': u'hi'}
```

In the console giving the error:

```
bundle.js:830 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: 
object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use 
an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the 
React add-ons. Check the render method of `NewComponent`.
```

and I was not able to print only the value of a specific key. 
need help

Edits:
As suggested by @im_benton and @TW80000 I have some changes.

First I used bson_json_util.dumps while sending the cursor so that i'm sending a string not a list.

```
return render_template('index.html', cursor = dumps(cursor))
```

Then in the pug file, I used window to create global variable and send the cursor to React

```
block content
#demo
script
  | window.data = {{ cursor }};
```

Then in the React file, I tried to parse the string to JSON and render it iterating through it.

```
componentWillMount(){
console.log("Mounting Components");
let data = window.data;
console.log(data);
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
this.setState({myData: data});
}

render() {
    return this.state.myData.map(item => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                <p>{item.description}</p>
            </div>
        );
    })
}
```

Still, i'm getting an empty array in console.log and if I don't use dumps an undefined object.

```
Mounting Components
bundle.js:20844 Array(0)
localhost/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at NewComponent.componentWillMount (bundle.js:20845)
at bundle.js:6685
at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js:6412)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (
```

Can you Help?

Comment: getting data from your html tag seems like an awful idea.

Comment: Can you set cursor to be a window object at least? Then you should probably hydrate that in to a reducer but start at just setting it to window.

Comment: like this in your pug file

````
script.
  window.data="#{cursor}";
```
then in your react component
```
this.setState({myData: window.data}); //set the state
```

Comment: @im_benton yes I understand getting data from HTML tag was awful, Thank you for your idea appreciate it. I have made changes to the code and still getting some errors can you please help me with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're trying to render a plain object. This isn't allowed. You need to render a string, an element, or some other valid type.

I'm assuming that since you're using h3 tags you want to put the object's title in that spot. You could do something like

```
<h3>{this.state.myData.title}</h3>
```

if `myData` is a single object (I can't quite tell from your code). If `myData` is an array of objects, you could do something like:

```
render() {
    return this.state.myData.map(item => {
        return (
            <div key={item._id}>
                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                <p>{item.description}</p>
            </div>
        );
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I originally was using a single object but your idea seemed more helpful. so I used your and @im_benton idea and made some changes. still getting some error though. can you help me out

Comment: Your best bet is to open a new question with your new problem. If you tag me in a comment I can have a look at it.

Comment: I have raised a new question taking your advise its working fine but something wrong with the list iteration. Can you help? This is the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908668/you-may-have-returned-undefined-an-array-or-some-other-invalid-object-rendering