# You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object rendering state data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, iteration

Have been facing issue while iterating through a list and printing elements in React.

The React Code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class NewComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {myData: []}
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        let data = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        this.setState({myData: data});
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.myData.map((item) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                <p>{item.description}</p>
            </div>
            );
         });
       }
     }


ReactDOM.render(
    <NewComponent />,
    document.getElementById('demo')
 )
```

And I'm getting an error of:

```
bundle.js:830 Uncaught Error: NewComponent.render(): A valid React element 
(or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or 
some other invalid object.
```

I'm pretty sure there is some issue with returns in the render function of the
Not sure what is the issue though.

**EDITS**

I have made the following edits, the error is not there anymore but nothing is rendering.

```
renderList() {
console.log("Running");
return  this.state.myData.map((item) => {
    <div>
      <h3>{item.title}</h3>
      <p>{item.description}</p>
    </div>
  });
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.myData);
    if(this.state.myData.length)
        return <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
    else
        return <div>Loading...</div>
 }
```

In Chrome console I'm getting:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
 0:{_id: {…}, description: "hello", title: "sankit"}
 1:{_id: {…}, description: "lets add some thing new", title: "hi"}
 length:2
 _proto_:Array(0)

 Running
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is extract your js code from the render method in a separate method like so:

```
renderList() {
   return this.state.myData.map((item) => {
      <div>
       <h3>{item.title}</h3>
       <p>{item.description}</p>
      </div>
   })
}
```

then in your render method:

```
render() {
  if(this.state.myData.length){
    return (
       <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
    );
  }
  else
  {
    return (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Amr the error is not there anymore but it's not rendering anything now.

Comment: when you console log `this.state.myData` in the render function  what is the output you receive?

Comment: I get this (2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{_id: {…}, description: "hello", title: "sankit"}
1
:
{_id: {…}, description: "lets add some thing new", title: "hi"}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: it would be better if you add a code snippet so it's easier to debug

Comment: I have mentioned the changes in the main log in the edits column

Comment: My code should be working. I am sorry i can't reproduce the problem without a code snippet.

Comment: I have figured out the issue, there  must be another return statement inside renderlist function  covering the divs together, Thanks for the help Amr :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with root element like `div`,
React ver 15 render functions supports only returning one element.

```
 render() {
    <div>{this.state.myData.map((item) =>
        <div>
            <h3>{item.title}</h3>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
        </div>
          )}</div>
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change like this, While you using `map` should use `key` attribute for index

```
makeUI() {
        if(!this.state.myData.length)
            return

        return this.state.myData.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                <p>{item.description}</p>
            </div>
            )
         })
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            { this.makeUI() }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the return in renderList -> .map

This should work.

```
renderList() {
    return this.state.myData.map((item) => {
        return (      
            <div>
            <h3>{item.title}</h3>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
            </div>
        );
    });
}

render() {
    if(this.state.myData.length){
        return (
            <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
        );
    }
    else {
        return (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        );
    }
}
```