# You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const renderCategories = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return props.categories.map(category => (
    <Category
      key={category.categoryID}
      category={category}
      isSelected={props.selectedCategory === category.categoryID}
      setSelectedCategory={props.setSelectedCategory}
    />
  ));
};
```

This is the function which returns the iterated categories. I think I am making some mistake in the syntax and that is why I am getting the following error , `You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.` I know this is a common question but I couldn't find a solution with respect to my code.

Comment: What version of React are you using?

Comment: @riwu - I am using 15.4.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908845/2138752

Comment: How do you use `renderCategories()` in your `render()` function? Could you add the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning array in a render function is only supported in [React v16.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings).

You need to wrap it around a `div` or something:

```
return (
  <div>
    {props.categories.map((category) => (
      <Category
        key={category.categoryID}
        category={category}
        isSelected={props.selectedCategory === category.categoryID}
        setSelectedCategory={props.setSelectedCategory}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: @YashSharma Don't forget that you could also upgrade to React 16 if your project allows for it. Then you will be fine returning arrays.