# What is this format how to convert it to json in JS

Tags: javascript, python

I am using parallelbots api to get sentiment analysis and in python the api returned

```
{u'probabilities': {u'positive': 0.214111, u'neutral': 0.66828, u'negative': 0.11761}, u'usage': u'By accessing ParallelDots API or using information generated by ParallelDots API, you are agreeing to be bound by the ParallelDots API Terms of Use: http://www.paralleldots.com/terms-and-conditions', u'sentiment': u'neutral'}
```

Is this a unicode format or some other, how to convert it into JSON so that i can use it in JS

Comment: That's a dictionary, with [unicode strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2464959/3001761). Did you look into Python's `json` module?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use python [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), `json.dumps()`.

```
import json
data = {u'probabilities': {u'positive': 0.214111, u'neutral': 0.66828, u'negative': 0.11761}, u'usage': u'By accessing ParallelDots API or using information generated by ParallelDots API, you are agreeing to be bound by the ParallelDots API Terms of Use: http://www.paralleldots.com/terms-and-conditions', u'sentiment': u'neutral'}
print data
data = json.dumps(data)
print data
```