# What and why is the small u in {u'key': value} printed out from the list of collections.Counter item

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I create a list of `Counter` item named `calc_comp`.

```
calc_comp = [sum((Counter(composition[aa]) for aa in 'ACDEDE'), Counter())]
print calc_comp
out>> [Counter({'H': 34, 'C': 24, 'O': 14, 'N': 6, 'S': 1})]
```

Then I append `calc_comp` into `pandas DataFrame`

```
df_M = pd.DataFrame()
df_M = df_M.append(pd.DataFrame({'comp': pd.Series(calc_comp)}), ignore_index=True)
print df_M

out>>
                                               comp
0  {u'H': 34, u'C': 24, u'S': 1, u'O': 14, u'N': 6}
```

What is the small `u` in front of each key of the output? Why is it printed out only at this point but never before?

Comment: Flagging as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2464959/1860929