# Excel file to Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have an Excel table where Column A is a list of emails and column B is a customer ID.

I need to create a Python dictionary and have `key=email address` and `value = customer ID`.

Desired results:

```
dict = {email@domain.com :'customer ID'}
```

My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
excel = "excel_file.xlsx"
list_dict = pd.read_excel(excel, index_col=0).to_dict()
print list_dict
```

However the dictionary is printing like this:

```
{u'customer ID': {u'email@domain.com': u'customer ID}}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the u prefix in a Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string)

Comment: For making this question self-contained, please post a short snippet that constructs the DataFrame with 2-3 lines in-place, without having to refer to a unavailable Excel file. Your question seems to be mostly about the to-dict conversion, not the input format. (Hint: simply reproducing the output of `df.head()` returned by `pd.read_excel(...)` should be enough.)

Answer (score 1):

If your excel file looks like this:

[image]

Then you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
excel = "excel_file.xlsx"
list_dict = pd.read_excel(excel, header=None).to_dict('list')
print {k: v for k, v in zip(*list_dict.values())}
```

(tested on Python3, im sure it works in Python2 as well -> be careful about Unicode)

Output:

```
C:\projects\python\test\so_pandas_dict>python main.py
{'example@gmail.com': 'customer ID', 'example1@gmail.com': 'customer ID1'}
```

Comment: Then it's a problem with your Excel file. If you have the exact same file scheme as I've shown you, then it works. You probably have more columns, or something like this. Then you could replace `zip(*list_dict.values())` with `zip(*(list_dict.values()[:2]))` if the columns you want to get are A and B

Comment: ahh it was, however I still see the ubnicode {u'email@.com':u'link here'}

Comment: Its because you use Python2, not Python3

Comment: If that's all, you don't have any following questions, you can accept my answer