# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:Python27ExcelBook.xls'

Tags: robotframework

I am just trying to write in the excel sheet 'Hello'.

Getting the following error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: u'C:Python27ExcelBook.xls'

```
Open Excel            C:\Python27\ExcelBook.xls
Put String To Cell    Sheet1  0    0     Hello
Save Excel            C:\Python27\ExcelBook.xls
```

This is the correct path but not sure where the 'u' coming from...

Answer (score 2):

Take a close look at the error:

```
No such file or directory: u'C:Python27ExcelBook.xls'
```

Notice that the error says `C:Python27...`, not `C:\Python27\...`

Robot uses the backslash as an escape character, so when you do `C:\Python27\ExcelBook.xls`, all the keyword sees is `C:Python27ExcelBook.xls`.

Use forward slashes, or use double-backslashes.

```
Open Excel C:\\Python27\\ExcelBook.xls
```

-or-

```
Open Excel C:/Python27/ExcelBook.xls
```

This is covered in the user guide, in a section titled [Escaping](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#escaping)

Comment: Thank you Bryan for replying.  I think they did not work for me. When I try C:\\Python27\\ExcelBook.xls the out put is:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Python27\\ExcelBook.xls'

When I try C:/Python27/ExcelBook.xls, the output is:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:/Python27/ExcelBook.xls'

I think the latter solution looks better but the 'u' is puzzling to me.  Not sure if I am doing anything else wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The u'some_text' is to indicate it is a unicode string [[What's the u prefix in a Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string]). Maybe try opening with something like:

```
filename = str(whatEverYourStringNameWas)
# open...
# or:
filename = bytes(whateverYourStringNameWas, 'ASCII')
# open...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am sorry I am new to RIDE robot framework and not sure how I can implement above solution.  Will you please elaborate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works double backslash, in case not working please change the file excess by right clicking on the file in advance section.