# Convert pandas dataframe to tuple of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have the following pandas **dataframe** df:

```
     Description    Code
0    Apples         014
1    Oranges        015
2    Bananas        017
3    Grapes         021
```

I need to convert it to a tuple of tuples, like this:

```
my_fruits = ( ('Apples', '014'), 
              ('Oranges', '015'), 
              ('Bananas', '017'), 
              ('Grapes', '021')
            )
```

Can you help me, please? I have tried the following code but it does not return what I really want:

```
list(zip(df.columns,df.T.values.tolist()))
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 12):

Would something like this work?

```
tuple(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

Comment: I prefer this way because it is more generic and I do not need to hard code the column names. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `zip` the two columns:

```
tuple(zip(df.Description, df.Code))
# (('Apples', 14), ('Oranges', 15), ('Bananas', 17), ('Grapes', 21))
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked!! Do you know how I can remove the u sign before each string? it says  u('Apples', u '014')

Comment: It just means [your strings are in unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string)

Comment: You probably are using python 2. As commented @TheHCA, it indicates the strings are unicode. You can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols) to convert unicode to ascii if you want them in ascii and don't mind losing some information on non-ascii characters. But generally you should be fine leaving the `u` alone.

Comment: @Psidom, I understood your point. However, it always fails because a tuple does not have that attribute encode/decode :(

Comment: You can't directly encode and decode a tuple; It has to be on the strings, something like `tuple((x.encode('ascii'), y.encode('ascii')) for x, y in zip(df.Description, df.Code))`.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not recommended for large dataframes, you can also use apply

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Apples', '014'], 
                   ['Oranges', '015'],
                   ['Bananas', '017'],
                   ['Grapes', '021']], columns = ['Fruit', 'Value'])

my_fruits = tuple(df[['Fruit','Value']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
my_fruits
```

Giving:

```
(('Apples', '014'), ('Oranges', '015'), ('Bananas', '017'), ('Grapes', '021'))
```

Use `df.columns` instead of explicitly typing out the column names if you want it to be more generic.