# How to remove prefixed u from a unicode string?

Tags: python-2.7, list, set, lda

I am reading the lines from a CSV file; I am applying LDA algorithm to find the most common topic, after data processing in doc_processed, I am getting 'u' in every word but why? Please suggest me to remove 'u' from the doc+processed, my code in Python 2.7 is

```
data = [line.strip() for line in open("/home/dnandini/test/h.csv", 'r')]

stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))# stop words
exclude = set(string.punctuation) #to reomve the punctuation
lemma = WordNetLemmatizer() # to map with parts of speech

def clean(doc):

    stop_free = " ".join([i for i in doc.lower().split() if i not in stop])
    punc_free = ''.join(ch for ch in stop_free if ch not in exclude)
    normalized = " ".join(lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in punc_free.split())
    shortword = re.compile(r'\W*\b\w{1,2}\b')
    output=shortword.sub('', normalized)   
    return output  
doc_processed = [clean(doc) for doc in data]
```

Output as doc_processed -

```
 [u'amount', u'ze69heneicosadien11one', u'trap', u'containing', u'little', u'microg', u'zz69ket', u'attracted', u'male', u'low', u'population', u'level', u'indicating', u'potent', u'sex', u'attractant', u'trap', u'baited', u'z6ket', u'attracted', u'male', u'windtunnel', u'bioassay', u'least', u'100fold', u'attractive', u'male', u'zz69ket', u'improvement', u'trap', u'catch', u'occurred', u'addition', u'z6ket', u'various', u'binary', u'mixture', u'zz69ket', u'including', u'female', u'ratio', u'ternary', u'mixture', u'zz69ket']
```

Answer (score 0):

the `u'some string'` format means it is a unicode string. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string) for more details on unicode strings themselves, but the easiest way to fix this is likely to `str.encode` the result before returning it from `clean`.

```
def clean(doc):
    # all as before until
    output = shortword.sub('', normalized).encode()
    return output
```

Note that attempting to encode unicode code points that don't translate directly to the default encoding (which appears to be ASCII. See `sys.getdefaultencoding()` on your system to check) will throw an error here. You can handle the error in various ways be defining the `errors` kwarg to encode.

```
s.encode(errors="ignore")  # omit the code point that fails to encode
s.encode(errors="replace")  # replace the failing code point with '?'
s.encode(errors="xmlcharrefreplace") # replace the failing code point with ' '
# Note that the " " above is U+FFFD, the Unicode Replacement Character.
```