# Odd placeholder or pre-statement on string declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x, iota

This is part of a code example I came across regarding the IOTA project. Python is new to me so I am trying to walk through each line. I got to this line and couldn't figure out why the "u" exists between the variable declaration and the string. I tested it independently with and without the `"u"` and the output is the same. Just trying to understand why it is there.

```
chars = u'9ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

I also came across another example using the same structure but with the letter `"b"`.

```
MySeed = b"WKQDUZTGFKSSLACUCHHLZRKZBHSDSCEBHKUPDLKFBQALEBKDMFRPUQGZRXAADPG9TSRTZGGBZOFRJCFMM"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `u` stands for Unicode and `b` stands for bytes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string

Comment: Thank you, I tried searching but all I got back was string information, nothing about the data type. Sorry for the repeat question.