# Beautiful Soup - meaning of letter 'u' in documentation

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Can anyone advise the meaning of the letter 'u' in this example output from Beautiful Soup documentation?

soup.title.string

## u'The Dormouse's story'

Thank you

Comment: This is Unicode according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464968/13507154) answer.

Comment: In Python 2, this meant a Unicode string