# unbalanced parenthesis regex

Tags: python, regex, data-processing, emoticons, unix-text-processing

```
!pip install emot
from emot.emo_unicode import EMOTICONS_EMO
def convert_emoticons(text):
    for emot in EMOTICONS_EMO:
        text = re.sub(u'\('+emot+'\)', "_".join(EMOTICONS_EMO[emot].replace(",","").split()), text)
        return text

text = "Hello :-) :-)"
convert_emoticons(text)
```

I'm trying to run the above code in google collab, but it gives the following error: `unbalanced parenthesis at position 4`

My undesrtanding from the re module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) tells that `'\(any_expression'\)'` is correct way to use, but I still get the error. So, I'have tried replacing `'\(' + emot + '\)` with:

1. `'(' + emot + ')'`, it gives the same error
2. `'[' + emot + ']'`, it gives the following output: `Hello Happy_face_or_smiley-Happy_face_or_smiley Happy_face_or_smiley-Happy_face_or_smiley`

The correct output should be `Hello Happy_face_smiley Happy_face_smiley` for `text = "Hello :-) :-)"`

Can someone help me fix the problem?

Comment: Note that if you're writing in Python 3, the `u` prefix [is now redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464968/11659881).

Comment: What is the point of the parentheses?

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow! Please see how to create a [mre] and then [edit] the question to include an example. It is not necessary to loop through "EMOTICONS_EMO", just pick an instance of `emot` that produces the error and use that explicitly so we can verify your error.

Comment: Perhaps you need `text = "Hello (-: :-)"` :-)

Comment: First off, it's better to use "raw" strings when defining REs `r"..."`. Those don't interpret escapes specially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty tricky using regex, as you'd **first** need to escape the metachars in the regex that are contained in the emoji, such as :`)` and :`(`, which is why you get the unbalanced parens. So, you'd need to do something like this first:

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'([()...])', r'%s\1' % '\\\\', ':)'))
:\)
```

But I'd suggest just doing a straight replacement since you already have a mapping that you're iterating through it. So we'd have:

```
from emot.emo_unicode import EMOTICONS_EMO
def convert_emoticons(text):
    for emot in EMOTICONS_EMO:
        text = text.replace(emot, EMOTICONS_EMO[emot].replace(" ","_"))
    return text


text = "Hello :-) :-)"
convert_emoticons(text)
# 'Hello Happy_face_smiley Happy_face_smiley'
```