# Can I safely remove all u-strings from a project that will only use python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work on a project that includes many `u"string"` in its codebase,

I want to know if I can safely remove the `u` in front of all those strings knowing that the project will only use Python 3 from now on (it used to use both python 2 and 3)

I have only [one source](https://bugs.python.org/issue33551) that says :

> "The string prefix u is used exclusively for compatibility with Python
> 2."

Comment: Yes, in Python 3 the u is redundant: [What's the u prefix in a Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I think you can. Unicode strings are not necessary in Python 3, because all strings are stored as Unicode by default, [as stated here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The sentence you quoted means that `u"string"` is in python3 only for compatibility.

In python 3 all strings are unicode so the `u` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I did run test using [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) tool and it did change u-string to normal string, `ustring.py` file before

```
x = u"string"
print(x)
```

after `2to3 -w ustring.py`

```
x = "string"
print(x)
```