# What does the 'u' symbol mean in front of string values?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Yes in short i would like to know why am I seeing a u in front of my keys and values.

I am rendering a form. The form has  check-box for the particular label and one text field for the ip address. I am creating a dictionary with keys being the label which are hardcoded in the list_key and values for the dictionary are taken from the form input (list_value). The dictionary is created but it is preceded by u for some values. here is the sample output for the dictionary:

```
{u'1': {'broadcast': u'on', 'arp': '', 'webserver': '', 'ipaddr': u'', 'dns': ''}}
```

can someone please explain what I am doing wrong. I am not getting the error when i simulate similar method in pyscripter. Any suggestions to improve the code are welcome. Thank you

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import webapp2
import itertools
import cgi

form ="""
    <form method="post">
    FIREWALL 
    <br><br>
    <select name="profiles">
        <option value="1">profile 1</option>
        <option value="2">profile 2</option>
        <option value="3">profile 3</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    Check the box to implement the particular policy
    <br><br>

    <label> Allow Broadcast
        <input type="checkbox" name="broadcast">
    </label>
    <br><br>

    <label> Allow ARP
        <input type="checkbox" name="arp">
    </label><br><br>

    <label> Allow Web traffic from external address to internal webserver
        <input type="checkbox" name="webserver">
    </label><br><br>

    <label> Allow DNS
        <input type="checkbox" name="dns">
    </label><br><br>

    <label> Block particular Internet Protocol  address
        <input type="text" name="ipaddr">
    </label><br><br>

    <input type="submit">   
    </form>
"""
dictionarymain={}

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):  
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)

    def post(self):
        # get the parameters from the form 
        profile = self.request.get('profiles')

        broadcast = self.request.get('broadcast')
        arp = self.request.get('arp')
        webserver = self.request.get('webserver')
        dns =self.request.get('dns')
        ipaddr = self.request.get('ipaddr')


        # Create a dictionary for the above parameters
        list_value =[ broadcast , arp , webserver , dns, ipaddr ]
        list_key =['broadcast' , 'arp' , 'webserver' , 'dns' , 'ipaddr' ]

        #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] ='text/plain'
        #self.response.out.write(profile)

        # map two list to a dictionary using itertools
        adict = dict(zip(list_key,list_value))
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] ='text/plain'
        self.response.out.write(adict)

        if profile not in dictionarymain:
            dictionarymain[profile]= {}
        dictionarymain[profile]= adict

        #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] ='text/plain'
        #self.response.out.write(dictionarymain)

        def escape_html(s):
            return cgi.escape(s, quote =True)



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: Is your actual question "Why am I seeing a `u` in front of my keys and values"?

Comment: And you don't show anywhere that you are getting an error in the first place.

Comment: That's because they're unicode strings:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599625/python-string-prints-as-ustring

Answer (score 196, accepted):

The 'u' in front of the string values means the string is a Unicode string. Unicode is a way to represent more characters than normal ASCII can manage. The fact that you're seeing the `u` means you're on Python 2 - strings are Unicode by default on Python 3, but on Python 2, the `u` in front distinguishes Unicode strings. The rest of this answer will focus on Python 2.

You can create a Unicode string multiple ways:

```
>>> u'foo'
u'foo'
>>> unicode('foo') # Python 2 only
u'foo'
```

But the real reason is to represent something like this ([translation here](http://translate.google.com/#ru%7Cen%7C%D0%9E%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%81%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9)):

```
>>> val = u'Ознакомьтесь с документацией'
>>> val
u'\u041e\u0437\u043d\u0430\u043a\u043e\u043c\u044c\u0442\u0435\u0441\u044c \u0441 \u0434\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0435\u0439'
>>> print val
Ознакомьтесь с документацией
```

For the most part, Unicode and non-Unicode strings are interoperable on Python 2.

There are other symbols you will see, such as the "raw" symbol `r` for telling a string not to interpret backslashes. This is extremely useful for writing regular expressions.

```
>>> 'foo\"'
'foo"'
>>> r'foo\"'
'foo\\"'
```

Unicode and non-Unicode strings can be equal on Python 2:

```
>>> bird1 = unicode('unladen swallow')
>>> bird2 = 'unladen swallow'
>>> bird1 == bird2
True
```

but not on Python 3:

```
>>> x = u'asdf' # Python 3
>>> y = b'asdf' # b indicates bytestring
>>> x == y
False
```

Comment: Thank you ..just to make it clear, what i understand that i will not get error operating on dictionary with string represented as unicode.

Comment: @user1488987: Correct. You can have unicode in your dict

Comment: is raw string the same thing as byte string?

Comment: @OmarKhazamov no a raw string means python will not interpret special characters. You don't have to escape "\n" as "\\n" for example. It's better to use a raw string when writing a regular expression, for instance. Bytes are entirely different.

Comment: @jdi what's the use case of non-unicode strings? (i.e why someone would want to use them if unicode are available in both python2 and python3)

Comment: @OmarKhazamov bytes are not encoded for visual representation. There are many binary formats that are meant to be read and written and transferred around. But they do not have a representation that can be usefully encoded into unicode

Answer (score 12):

This is a feature, not a bug.

See http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html, specifically the 'unicode type' section.