# Scrapy item pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrappy spider and my own item pipeline

```
 value['Title'] = item['Title'][0] if ('Title' in item) else ''
        value['Name'] = item['Name'][0] if ('CompanyName' in item) else ''
        value['Description'] = item['Description'][0] if ('Description' in item) else ''
```

When i do this i am getting the value prefixed with `u`

Example : When i pass the value to o/p and print it

```
value['Title'] = u'hospital'
```

What went wrong in my code  and why i am getting `u` and how to remove it

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks,

Comment: It's OK, it's just a Unicode string

Comment: @ForceBru how can i remove it and pass the item

Comment: Is `value['Title']=...` the output you get?

Answer (score 2):

The u means that the string is represented as unicode. You can remove the u by passing the string to str. `str(u'test')`. But you can treat is as normal string for most purposes. For example

```
>>> u'test' == 'test'
True
```

If you have characters that cannot be represented with plain ascii you should keep the unicode way. If you call str on non ascii characters you will get an exception.

```
>>> test=u'বাংলা'
>>> test
u'\u09ac\u09be\u0982\u09b2\u09be'
>>> str(test)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The `u` is not part of the string, it is just a way to indicate the type of the string.

```
>>> type('test')
<type 'str'>
>>> type(u'test')
<type 'unicode'>
```

Se the following question for more details:

[What does the 'u' symbol mean in front of string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values)

Comment: str(u'test')  Will it remove all the unicode characters or only the "u". The reason is i my get Unicode from webpages. That's why

Comment: See my edit. The u is not part of the actual string. It is just a way to specify what type the string have.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the `u` sign you may encode the string as ASCII like this: `value['Title'].encode("ascii")`.