# Parse unicode JSON string

Tags: json, python-2.7, unicode

I've some difficulties to parse a unicode JSON string.

sample:

```
js = "{'to': 1234, 'message': u'sample message', 'user': 65773722, 'msgId': 28198}"
```

I want to iterate the JSON object to retrieve the values.

I've already tried, json.dumps, json.loads and js.decode('unicode-escape'),
but I keep getting error messages.

Please help..I'm stuck !

Many thanks !

Comment: That is not a valid json string. The string should be enclosed using " and not ', also the u'' is not valid. 

Use something like http://jsonlint.com/ to validate. If you use Chrome I would recommend https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa to validate and view json well formatted.

Comment: `js` is not a unicode string, but a bytestring that happens to contain a unicode literal.  It is not clear whether you are trying to construct a valid json string, or whether you are trying to parse a string that someone else gave you (that only pretends to be valid json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not valid json

```
s = "{'to': 1234, 'message': u'sample message', 'user': 65773722, 'msgId': 28198}"
valid = s.replace("u'", "'")
supervalid = v.replace("'", '"')
json.loads(super_valid)
```

Comment: I'am convinced  (except for the errors in the variables)  ;-))

Comment: Yes =), valid = s.replace("u'", "'"); supervalid = valid.replace("'", '"'); json.loads(supervalid)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately someone goofed, and that's not JSON.

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(js)
{'to': 1234, 'message': u'sample message', 'user': 65773722, 'msgId': 28198}
```

Comment: @Ignaciao; I do not understand what you mean. Please explain !

Comment: String not JSON. JSON functions not work. Find other way to parse.

Comment: Treat it as a dictionary maybe ?

Comment: It's a string. It needs to be parsed before you can access it.

Comment: It is JSON, the u at the beginning of the string shows that it's encoded in unicode [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values)

Comment: @Darbio: The `u` prefix only applies to *Python* strings. It is *not* valid in JSON.