# django request.Post value not showing properly

Tags: django

I have a input field as follows

```
<input type="text" name="first_name"/>
```

when I call it from view.py

```
first_name = request.POST['first_name'],
```

I get value as following

```
(u'sazzad',)
```

here `sazzad` is my input but i get that extra part `(u'',)`

how to fix this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the 'u' symbol mean in front of string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values)

Comment: You should not access data directly from request.POST but through a django form module. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/

Comment: I am not binding it to any db table. do i need to go through this process @luc

Comment: It has nothing to do with db tables. Forms provide a lot of useful functionality around validation and cleaning; you should use them unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: @Sazzad I fully agree with Daniel comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have accidentally added a comma to the end of the line:

```
first_name = request.POST['first_name'],
                                       ^ trailing comma
```

That means that `first_name` is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) `(u'sazzad',)`, instead of a string `u'sazzad'`.

You should remove this comma.

As @rnevius says in the comments, the `u''` prefix just means that it's a unicode string, you don't have to worry about this.