# Scraping with BeautifulSoup: want to scrape entire column including header and title rows

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a hold of the data under the columns having the code "SEVNYXX", where "XX" are the numbers that follow (eg. 01, 02, etc) on the [site](http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html) using Python.

With the code below I can get the first row of all the Columns data that I want. However, is there a way I could include the header and row Titles to these?

I know I have the Headers, but I was wondering if there is a way to include these in the data that is outputted? 
And, also how could I look to include all the rows?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

page = request.urlopen('http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

desired_table = soup.findAll('table')[2]

# Find the columns you want data from
headers = desired_table.findAll('th')
desired_columns = []
for th in headers:
    if 'SVENY' in th.string:
        desired_columns.append(headers.index(th))

# Iterate through each row grabbing the data from the desired columns
rows = desired_table.findAll('tr')

for row in rows[1:]:
    cells= row.findAll('td')
    for column in desired_columns:
        print(cells[column].text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

I added `th.getText()` and created a list on the desired columns which pulled the column name, and then added `row_name = row.findNext('th').getText()` to get the row.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

page = request.urlopen('http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

desired_table = soup.findAll('table')[2]

# Find the columns you want data from
headers = desired_table.findAll('th')
desired_columns = []
for th in headers:
    if 'SVENY' in th.string:
        desired_columns.append([headers.index(th), th.getText()])

# Iterate through each row grabbing the data from the desired columns
rows = desired_table.findAll('tr')

for row in rows[1:]:
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    row_name = row.findNext('th').getText()
    for column in desired_columns:
        print(cells[column[0]].text, row_name, column[1])
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I tried the code you suggested and an Error pops up at `row_name = row.findNext('th').getText()` saying `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'`?

Comment: @user131983 That's strange.. Code works perfect for me, example: `0.3487 2015-06-05 SVENY01`. You have the code copied exactly from what I wrote?

Comment: Sorry you're right. I just realized that I actually changed my code  to use `urllib2` rather than `urllib` as I am now running this code on my laptop and have Python 2.7. So, now I do `url = "http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html"

content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)`. However, this results in the output: `(u'0.3487', u'2015-06-05', u'SVENY01')`. Would you know why this is? Thanks!

Comment: @user131983 Here's the answer to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values - The reason it's now showing is cause you're switching from Python 3.x (where it won't show) to 2.7 (where it is now showing).

Comment: Thanks a lot. One further question, did you get an `IndexError :list index out of range` for the line `cells[column[0]].text.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), row_name.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), column[1].encode('ascii', 'ignore')` ? I appear to be getting that.

Comment: I didn't get that... Did the code change at all beside you adding `.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` to each var?