# NLTK brown.words() returns different output

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk

for the command

`>>> brown.words()`

the expected output is

```
['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', ...]
```

But, when I tried this command I get an output as

```
[u'The', u'Fulton', u'County', u'Grand', u'Jury', ...]
```

Anyone knows why this is happening?

I was following these steps

1-installed Python 2.7.10 32-bit version

2-installed NLTK 3.0.5

3-go to Python IDLE

4-`>>> import nltk`

5-`>>> nltk.download()` then downloaded the required data collections

6-`>>> from nltk.corpus import brown`

7-`>>> brown.words()`

Answer (score 3):

The u in front of the string means it is being represented as unicode.

See [What does the 'u' symbol mean in front of string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values) for a solution