# python google api Bizarre Type of List

Tags: list, python-2.7, gmail-api

google's gmail api is frustrating! 
long story short, i need to extract the message id from a list of data but it doesn't appear to be any type of list i've dealt with before.
if my piece of data is

```
    {u'id': u'1518b43eb16ed26a', u'threadId': u'1518a3707c5313d2'},
    {u'id': u'1518b433b16ed262', u'threadId': u'1518a3707c5313d2'},
    {u'id': u'218b43eb16232e67', u'threadId': u'1518a3707c5313d2'},
    {u'id': u'4518b33eb16ed262', u'threadId': u'1518a3707c5313d2'},
```

I just need to extract the first 1518b43eb16ed26a. How could I do this without having to manually viewing the ids and retyping them?

Comment: The `u` simply means that the string is [represented as unicode.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values) :)

Comment: DUH! thank you!

so would this be a dictionary then? 
i don't understand why each id is identical

Comment: The Gmail API returns [JSON](http://www.json.org/). You will have to parse this, to maybe a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) as you say. :)