# What is the "u" in results (Python)?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm reading this book "Python Text Processing with NLTK", and on the book the results are:

```
>>> stopwords.fileids()
['danish', 'dutch', 'english', 'finnish', 'french', 'german', 'hungarian', 'italian', 'norwegian', 'portuguese', 'russian', 'spanish', 'swedish', 'turkish']
```

But as I run the codes in terminal, results are:

```
>>> stopwords.fileids()
[u'danish', u'dutch', u'english', u'finnish', u'french', u'german', u'hungarian', u'italian', u'norwegian', u'portuguese', u'russian', u'spanish', u'swedish', u'turkish']
```

What is the "u" in front of every string?

Comment: And of [What does the 'u' symbol mean in front of string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values)

Comment: Comparing two strings, one with prefix 'u' and the other without one, would still return True (prefect match) so in many cases you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: You're currently using Python 2. You'd want to switch to Python 3 for natural language processing, as it has superior text manipulation capabilities; this `u` prefix is also gone there. NLTK version 3.0 supports Python 3.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, if the user was using Python 2 with NLTK v. 2, there would be no unicode prefix, correct? The results in the text she is using were generated (presumably) with Python 2 and NLTK 2, and those results show *no* unicode prefix.

Comment: @Silenus perhaps; but by now anyone doing natural language processing should really be using both Python 3 and NLTK 3.

Answer (score 4):

The `u` stands for a string containing unicode

Which you can check for yourself by typing this in your python interpreter:

```
s = unicode('abcdef')
type(s) # <type 'unicode'>
t = u'unicode'
type(t) #<type 'unicode'>
```

More information on unicode strings [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) | [python3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type)