# Join list of strings and remove Unicode prefix

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have this output

```
[u'JACK', u'', u'ROSE', u'', u'JANE']
```

I want to remove the unicode from each element of a list and join them into a single string like that:

Output:

```
['JACK ROSE JANE']
```

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the u? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)

Comment: Note that the 'u' is not a character, it just describes the ' spark. So, instead of seeing `'stuff'`, you see `u'stuff'`, because the string is a unicode string, but its content is still `stuff`

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers are perfect. Just to show you another way:

```
result = [str(' '.join(filter(None, [u'JACK', u'', u'ROSE', u'', u'JANE'])))]
```

That's how to do it in functional paradigm :)
And it looks nice, huh?

Actually, you don't need to worry about 'u' prefix. It simply let's you(as a developer) know that string is represented as unicode. 
I've added "str" to hide it(convert to ascii string) but it doesn't really needed. Please check this answer:
[What does the 'u' symbol mean in front of string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values)

Comment: For me, it is important because i have to copy result into a raw input so i can't consider u'

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to program it. I prefer this:

```
output = str(" ".join(filter(None,[u'JACK', u'', u'ROSE', u'', u'JANE'])))
```

If you need list:

```
output = [str(" ".join(filter(None,[u'JACK', u'', u'ROSE', u'', u'JANE'])))]
```

Comment: I just posted the same :)

Answer (score -1):

In Python 2, use the `str` function to convert a unicode string to a normal string:

```
>>> unicodeString = u'stuff'
>>> normalString = str(unicodeString)
>>> print(unicodeString)
u'stuff'
>>> print(normalString)
'stuff'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> in_list = list(filter(lambda x: len(x)>0, [u'JACK', u'', u'ROSE', u'', u'JANE']))
>>> output = " ".join(in_list)                                                                   
>>> output
'JACK ROSE JANE'
```

Answer (score -1):

just for the sake of simplicity:

```
output = [' '.join([str(a) for a in [u'JACK', u'JANE', u'ROSE']])]
['JACK JANE ROSE']
```

tested in python2.7 and python3.5

Answer (score -1):

By using None in the filter() call, it removes all falsy elements. already by @Andrey

```
a = [u'JACK', u'', u'ROSE', u'', u'JANE']

c = [str(' '.join(filter(None, a)))]
print (c)
```

or iterate and get only True items, the contra argument here is the possibility of the string operators, o.lower,o.upper.....

```
b = [' '.join([o for o in a if o])]
print (b)
```