# How do I remove a character from strings in a list?

Tags: python, regex

I am working with a module called `PyDictionary`. Whenever it gets the synonym of a word, it creates a `list` of the synonyms, however when I try `print` the `list`, it has a `'u'` before the synonym, example:

```
[u'welcome', u'howdy', u'hi', u'greetings', u'bonjour']
```

I've tried: `synonym = re.sub('u','',synonym[0])`, and this works, but only prints `'welcome'`, not the entire `list`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The 'u' in front just means it is a unicode string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values

Comment: That's Python's way of letting you know it's a Unicode string. When you print the string however, the `u` will not be visible, so it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: `u` prefix means that the string is unicode. If you print it using the `print()` function it will not show that decorator (e.g. `print(your_list[0])`)

Comment: I'm using PyTTSX to read the synonyms. Using print(synonym[0]) prints a single item from the list, the first item. print(synonym[0:len(synonym)]) prints all the items, but the u is there. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @ElliotPoots - print it in a loop, e.g.: `for syn in synonym: print(syn)` or if you want single-line: `print(", ".join(synonym))`

Comment: @zwer That works. Thanks so much. Sorry, still learning the inns and outs of Python. Again, appreciated!

Comment: @zwer I am now doing something similar for the definition. I was wondering how I'd do it, I've attempted the fix for the synonym here, but it does not work.
`print("The definition for " + str(dWord) + " is: " + ", ".join(definition))
        for defini in definition:
            s_engine.say("The definition for " + str(dWord) + " is " + str(definition))
            s_engine.runAndWait()`
However the output is either 'Verb' or 'Noun' or the dictionary with the u.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the `list` to a `list` of `strings` you can use `list` comprehensions like:

```
result = [str(x) for x in synonym]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `u` you are seeing is not part of the string content, and therefore cannot be removed with regular expression substitution.   Instead, it should be considered ***part of the opening quote***. The syntax of the Python language itself allows for string literals to be defined with quotes that are inflected in this way. For example:

```
a = 'spam'
b = u'spam'   # in Python 2, a and b are different types
```

When you display the variable the way you would to a *programmer*, i.e. in such a way that the quote characters are visible (e.g. just typing `synonym[0]` at the prompt, or trying to `print` the whole list `synonym`,  or otherwise invoking Python's `repr()` mechanism on the strings) then the `u` will be visible too.   By contrast, when you display the variable as you would to a *user* (e.g. with `print synonym[0]`,  or by `join`ing the list and then `print`ing the resulting string) then, just as you would not expect to see the quote characters themselves, you will also not see the `u`.