# Encoding error in Python API response

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, python-requests

I am trying (for the first time) to use APIs with Python Requests module.

I need to get some data from the API and parse it as JSON. I was able to successfully get the intended response with Postman for chrome, while testing the query.

However, when I try to execute the same code with Python the data gets encoded incorrectly. I have tried .encode('utf-8) .encode('utf-8) on my data with no success. I have read the articles on encoding in python howto (https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) with no luck.

My code:

> import requests
>   r=requests.get("http://company.vtexcommercestable.com.br/api/oms/pvt/orders?per_page=100", headers={"Accept":"application/json","Content-Type":"application/json","X-VTEX-API-AppToken":"password","X-VTEX-API-AppKey":"testemail@gmail.com"});
>
> data = r.json()
>
> print r

The result:

> {u'stats': {u'stats': {u'totalItems': {u'Count': 113, u'Min': 0.0, u'Max': 0.0, u'Sum': 0.0, u'Missing': 0, u'SumOfSquares': 0.0, u'StdDev': 0.0, u'Facets': {}, u'Mean': 0.0}, u'totalValue':

I would need to remove "u' .." and add keep latin characters (accents and "ñ")

Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem after installing unicodecsv package, and replacing the original csv with

```
import unicodecsv as csv
```

Then, I was able to csv.writerow Unicode characters with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Those are unicode characters - [see this answer for a great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values).

You shouldn't have any issues evaluating those as regular characters in your logic, and therefore do not need to worry about "removing them".

Comment: Hi David, thank for your time, the problem is when I try to use the csv module with the writerow function, I get the following error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 84: ordinal not in range(128)".

I believe there is some basic encoding principle I don't understand :(