# Flask get_json does not return correct JSON

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask

I am having a problem decoding JSON with Flask.

From AJAX I send the following request:

```
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: 'http://localhost:5000/getSurveyResult/',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
async: true,
data: '{"1":"UTF-16","2":"Ja"}',
success: function () {
alert("Thanks!");
}
```

Server Side:

```
@app.route('/getSurveyResult/', methods=['POST'])
def get_survey_result():
    request_json = request.get_json()
    print request_json
    return "OK"
```

The print gives me this weird output and I cannot access the fields by using request_json[1]:

```
{u'1': u'UTF-16', u'2': u'Ja'}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `request_json[1]` and not `request_json['1']` ?

Comment: Yup, That's why I couldn't access it. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `u` that is in front of your strings in the printout signifies that the string is `unicode`, it's standard python behaviour, see here : [What does the 'u' symbol mean in front of string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values)

As for your `request_json` variable, the keys are both strings and would be accessed with `request_json["1"]` (Note the quotes around the `1`).

JSON only allows keys to be strings by design: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: Ty! That clears it up. Why have I never seen that u being there for dicts, that were created directly, without parsing from JSON?

Comment: No problem :). That has to do with Flask itself which is entirely based on unicode. So when the request is internally processed by Flask, it's Flask that converted the strings to unicode before serving them to your endpoint. More information can be found here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/unicode/