# Python Web Scraping BeautifulSoup - substring

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Second day on web scraping using Python. I am trying to pull a substring within a string. I wrote the following python code using BeautifulSoup:

```
 containers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"grid-tile "})
 container_test = containers[7]
 product_container = container_test.findAll("div",{"class":"product-
 swatches"})
 product = product_container[0].findAll("li")
 product[0].a.img.get("data-price")
```

This outputs the following:

```
'{"saleprice":"$39.90","price":""}'
```

How do I print out saleprice and price separately? Result should look like:

```
saleprice = $39.90
price = ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `json` module - specifically, [the `loads` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads), which loads JSON-formatted strings common on websites.

```
string = '{"saleprice":"$39.90","price":""}'
>>> import json
json_data = json.loads(string)
sale_price = json_data['saleprice']
price = json_date['price']
print(saleprice, price)
>>> (u'', u'$39.90')
```

The `u` preceding the string indicates that the string is unicode, which is well explained [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279428/5266746)

Additionally, you could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279428/5266746), as the string is formatted like a normal Python dictionary.  That process would be:

```
import ast
string = '{"saleprice":"$39.90","price":""}'
dict_representation_of_string = ast.literal_eval(string)
print(string.keys())
>>> ['price', 'saleprice']
```

Answer (score 0):

this link should be able to help
[Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

```
import ast

BSoutput = '{"saleprice":"$39.90","price":""}'
testing =  ast.literal_eval(BSoutput)
saleprice = testing['saleprice'] 
price = testing['price']
print "saleprice = " + saleprice
```