# Manipulating the list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a 2-element list like:

```
[(2, u'0.267*"sugar" + 0.266*"bad"'), (0, u'0.222*"father" + 0.222*"likes"')]
```

I want to get the first words of tuples that is I want to get a 2-element list as:

```
["sugar","father"]
```

I don't know how can I achive this since I am unfamilier with `u'` notation. Can anyone help or give some hints?

Comment: [Meaning of 'u' symbol in front of string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values)

Comment: This means the unicode string.

Comment: the `u` prefix only means it's a (python 2.x) unicode string. They work just like bytestrings (ordinary python 2.x strings) wrt/ string manipulation operations, so just treat them as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str` methods

**Ex:**

```
d = [(2, u'0.267*"sugar" + 0.266*"bad"'), (0, u'0.222*"father" + 0.222*"likes"')]
print([i[1].split("+")[0].split("*")[1].replace('"', "").strip() for i in d])
```

**Output:**

```
[u'sugar', u'father']
```

- `str.split` to split string by ("+" and "*")
- `str.replace` to replace extra quotes
- `str.strip` to remove all trailing or leading space.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the value of an index location using square brackets.

```
myList[index]
```

In nested lists:

```
myList[indexInOuterList][indexInInnerList]
```

For your situation:

```
myList[indexInList][indexInTuple]

mylist = [(2, u'0.267*"sugar" + 0.266*"bad"'), (0, u'0.222*"father" + 0.222*"likes"')]
myList[0][0] #This is the integer 2
```