# Django python send email with non-english characters

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I try to send email with  russian chracters, but as an output I get

> Subject:
>   (b'\xd0\xaf\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8e\xd1\x87\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba - 
>   \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0
>   \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0', 27)

This is my code:

```
subject = 'поступила оплата'
body = 'email body'
    send_mail(
                subject
                body,
                'from@gmail.com',
                ["to_email@test.com"],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
```

I tried

```
subject.encode('utf8') 
subject.decode('utf8')
subject.encode('utf8').decode('utf8')
codecs.utf_8_encode(subject)
```

But didn't help.
What do I do?

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Which version of Django?

Comment: @yorodm last version of django

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`subject = u'поступила оплата'`

The `u` in front of the string means the string has been represented as unicode. Letters before strings in Python are called "String Encoding declarations". Unicode is a way to represent more characters than normal ASCII can manage.

You can also convert to unicode like this:

`subject = unicode('поступила оплата')`

By the way, you **may** also need to declare the encoding in the beginning of the script, like this:

`#encoding:utf8`

---

Source: [What does the 'u' symbol mean in front of string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values)