# Pandas filtering off empty list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has a column 'Fruit' with something like this in it.

```
[u'']
[u'']
[u'']
[u'' u'apple' u'Orange']
[u'']
[u'']
```

I want to return only the items that have the [u''].

I have tried this using bool types and str len but there are some other places I might have an something like this

[u'apple']

```
df1 = d[d['Fruit'].str.len()== 0]
```

Returns nothing because it is counting it as 1.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? Also just use a map or something to check the length of the list. Actually, you don't even need map, just basic indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've represented your data frame is a bit weird.  Assuming that every entry within the `Fruit` column is in fact a list, the length of this is going to be 1 because each record is a list with one entry in it (at least in the data you've provided).

The `[u'']` records you're interested in are a list consisting of a simple empty string.  The `u` character you see in front of the string isn't part of the string but just denotes that the string is unicode, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values) for more information.

To solve your problem, you should be able to do

```
df1 = d[d['Fruit'] == ['']]
```

to pull back only rows with empty strings.

If you're still unclear what's going on, play around with this:

```
test = [u'']

test == ['']
>> True

test == ['', '']
>> False
```

Comment: I get the following error ValueError: Lengths must match to compare