# Why does Python 2's raw_input output unicode strings?

Tags: python, input, unicode, python-2.x

I tried the following on [Codecademy's Python lesson](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python)

```
hobbies = []

# Add your code below!
for i in range(3):
    Hobby = str(raw_input("Enter a hobby:"))
    hobbies.append(Hobby)

print hobbies
```

With this, it works fine but if instead I try

```
Hobby = raw_input("Enter a hobby:")
```

I get `[u'Hobby1', u'Hobby2', u'Hobby3']`. Where are the extra `u`s coming from?

Comment: [Python string prints as \[u'String'\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599625/python-string-prints-as-ustring) Maybe you can find answer here .

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I receive the same for both in Python 2.7. `u` means `Unicode` encoding.

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with the console it's running in?

Comment: I used CodeAcademy's web console. I think it runs 2.7

Comment: @KIDJourney it is not a duplicate: "why `raw_input()` returns Unicode" (while it should return bytestrings on Python 2) is a different question from "why printing a list that contains Unicode strings produces `[u'']`".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question's subject line might be a bit misleading: Python 2's [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) normally returns a byte string, NOT a Unicode string.

However, it *could* return a Unicode string if it or `sys.stdin` has been altered or replaced (by an application, or as part of an alternative implementation of Python).

Therefore, I believe @ByteCommander is on the right track with his comment:

> Maybe this has something to do with the console it's running in?

The Python used by Codecademy is ostensibly 2.7, but (a) it was implemented by compiling the Python interpreter to JavaScript using [Emscripten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emscripten) and (b) it's running in the browser; so between those factors, there could very well be some string encoding and decoding injected by Codecademy that isn't present in plain-vanilla CPython.

Note: I have not used Codecademy myself nor do I have any inside knowledge of its inner workings.

Comment: Just want to say this is almost definitely it. I came looking for a generic answer and it was 1000% because I was off-roading in the Codecademy Python 2.7 course. It must be something on their end. Good to know the default behavior is logical.

Answer (score 4):

`'u'` means its a unicode. You can also specify `raw_input().encode('utf8')` to convert to string.

Edited:
I checked in python 2.7 it returns byte string not unicode string. So problem is something else here.

Edited:
raw_input() returns unicode if sys.stdin.encoding is unicode.

In codeacademy python environment, sys.stdin.encoding and sys.stdout.decoding both are none and default endcoding scheme is ascii.

Python will use this default encoding only if it is unable to find proper encoding scheme from environment.

Comment: `raw_input()` in Python 2.X returns byte strings, not Unicode strings.  Something else is going on.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: there is no `raw_input()` on Python 3 and therefore it is safe to say that `raw_input()` always returns a bytestring unless a 3rd party module such as `win-unicode-console` overrides its behavior.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I did say `raw_input` reruns a byte string. What's your point? The answerer said the opposite.

Comment: @MarkTolonen you said *"raw_input() in Python 2.X returns byte strings"* that could be interpreted that it behaves differently on Python 3. I said *"there is no `raw_input()` on Python 3"*, to disambiguate. I'm agreeing with you, my comment is just an addition.

Comment: The main point here is that this answer provides blatantly incorrect information. :(  I understand that it could be accepted even though it's wrong, because the asker doesn't know any better. But how did it get multiple upvotes?

Comment: I've un-accepted the answer based on @John Y's comment.

Comment: So much wrong with this answer. "raw_input() returns unicode if sys.stdin.encoding is unicode" - `unicode` isn't an encoding and certainly not a valid value for `sys.stdin.encoding`.

Answer (score 3):

> Where are the extra `u`s coming from?

- `raw_input()` returns Unicode strings in your environment
- `repr()` is called for each item of a list if you print it (convert to string)
- the text representation (`repr()`) of a Unicode string is the same as Unicode literal in Python: `u'abc'`.

that is why `print [raw_input()]` may produce: `[u'abc']`.

You don't see `u''` in the first code example because `str(unicode_string)` calls the equivalent of `unicode_string.encode(sys.getdefaultencoding())` i.e., it converts Unicode strings to bytestrings—don't do it unless you mean it.

#### Can `raw_input()` return `unicode`?

[Yes](http://ideone.com/oGwDGT):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
"""Demonstrate that raw_input() can return Unicode."""
import sys

class UnicodeFile:
    def readline(self, n=-1):
        return u'\N{SNOWMAN}'

sys.stdin = UnicodeFile()
s = raw_input()
print type(s)
print s
```

Output:

```
<type 'unicode'>
☃
```

The practical example is `win-unicode-console` package which can replace `raw_input()` to support entering Unicode characters outside of the range of a console codepage on Windows. Related: here's [why `sys.stdout` should be replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5419/4279).

#### May `raw_input()` return `unicode`?

Yes.

[`raw_input()` is *documented* to return a ***string***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input):

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a *string*
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

***String*** in Python 2 is either a bytestring or Unicode string :`isinstance(s, basestring)`.

CPython *implementation* of `raw_input()` supports Unicode strings explicitly: [`builtin_raw_input()` can call `PyFile_GetLine()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/609ca416f4017d5e8f2e741c57827de584688cf7/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2101) and [`PyFile_GetLine()` considers bytestrings and Unicode strings to be strings—it raises  `TypeError("object.readline() returned non-string")` otherwise](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/609ca416f4017d5e8f2e741c57827de584688cf7/Objects/fileobject.c#L1578-L1632).

Answer (score 1):

You could encode the strings before appending them to your list:

```
hobbies = []

# Add your code below!
for i in range(3):
    Hobby = raw_input("Enter a hobby:")
    hobbies.append(Hobby.encode('utf-8')

print hobbies
```

Comment: In this case, the encoding is unncessary. It only needs it if the first line doesn't have str() to begin with