# Hashtags python html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml, hashtag

I want to extract all the hashtags from a given website:
For example, "I love #stack overflow because #people are very #helpful!"
This should pull the 3 hashtags into a table. 
In the website I am targeting there is a table with a #tag      description
So we can find       #love        this hashtag speaks about love

This is my work:

```
    #import the library used to query a website
    import urllib2
    #specify the url
    wiki = "https://www.symplur.com/healthcare-hashtags/tweet-chats/all"
    #Query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
    page = urllib2.urlopen(wiki)
    #import the Beautiful soup functions to parse the data returned from the 
     website
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    #Parse the html in the 'page' variable, and store it in Beautiful Soup 
    format
     soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    print soup.prettify()
    s = soup.get_text()
    import re
     re.findall("#(\w+)", s)
```

I have an  issues in the output : 
The first one is that the output look like this : 
[u'eeeeee',
 u'333333',
 u'222222',
 u'222222',
 u'222222',
 u'222222',
 u'222222',
 u'222222',
 u'222222',
 u'AASTGrandRoundsacute'

The output concatenate the Hashtag with the first word in the description. If I compare to the example I evoked before the output is 'lovethis'.

How can I do to extract only the one word after the hashtag.

Thank you

Comment: the 'u' is not really there. it is displayed by python to tell you that the string beside it is in [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). https://stackoverflow.com/a/599653/3072566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no need to use `regex` to parse the text you get from the page, you can use `BeautifulSoup` itself for that. I'm using Python3.6 in the code below, just to show the entire code, but the important line is `hashtags = soup.findAll('td', {'id':'tweetchatlist_hashtag'})`. Notice all hashtags in the table have `td` tag and `id` attribute `= tweetchatlist_hashtag`, so calling `.findAll` is the way to go here:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wiki = "https://www.symplur.com/healthcare-hashtags/tweet-chats/all"
page = requests.get(wiki).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

hashtags = soup.findAll('td', {'id':'tweetchatlist_hashtag'})
```

Now let's have a look at the first item of our list:

```
>>> hashtags[0]
<td id="tweetchatlist_hashtag" itemprop="location"><a href="https://www.symplur.com/healthcare-hashtags/aastgrandrounds/" title="#AASTGrandRounds">#AASTGrandRounds</a></td>
```

So we see that what we really want is the value of `title` attribute of `a`:

```
>>> hashtags[0].a['title']
'#AASTGrandRounds'
```

To proceed to get a list of all hashtags using list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [hashtag.a['title'] for hashtag in hashtags]
```

If you are not used with list comprehension syntax, the line above is similar to this:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> for hashtag in hashtags:
    lst.append(hashtag.a['title'])
```

`lst` then is the desired output, see the first 20 items of the list:

```
>>> lst[:20]
['#AASTGrandRounds', '#abcDrBchat', '#addictionchat', '#advocacychat', '#AetnaMyHealthy', '#AlzChat', '#AnatQ', '#anzOTalk', '#AskAvaility', '#ASPChat', '#ATtalk', '#autchat', '#AXSChat', '#ayacsm', '#bcceu', '#bccww', '#BCSM', '#benurse', '#BeTheDifference', '#bioethx']
```

Comment: Thank you, running your solution I got the error:  ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.symplur.com', port=443): retries with url: /healthcare-hashtags/tweet-chats/all (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000682F0F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10060] Une tentative de connexion a \xe9chou\xe9 car le parti connect\xe9 n\x92a pas r\xe9pondu convenablement au-del\xe0 d\x92une certaine dur\xe9e ou une connexion \xe9tablie a \xe9chou\xe9 car l\x92h\xf4te de connexion n\x92a pas r\xe9pondu',))

Comment: It is a proxy problem !